# Delete zero values from Array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with name "ids" and some values like ['0','567','956','0','34']. Now I need to remove "0" values from this array.
**ids.remove ("0");** is not working.

Comment: Well, `Array.prototype.remove` does not exist, so it cannot work ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use splice method in javascript. Try this function:

```
function removeElement(arrayName,arrayElement)
 {
    for(var i=0; i<arrayName.length;i++ )
     { 
        if(arrayName[i]==arrayElement)
            arrayName.splice(i,1); 
      } 
  }
```

Parameters are:

```
arrayName:-      Name of the array.
arrayElement:-   Element you want to remove from array
```

Comment: what is 1. I think i need to use "0" insted of "1" in my case right?

Comment: @vissupepala: No. Read the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice . It means remove 1 element starting from index `i`.

Comment: Nope. Its the number of element you want to remove. you have to pass `0` in `arrayElement`

Comment: That will fail if the array has two consecutive zeroes.

Comment: @TimDown is right, you would need to do `i--` in the `if` statement to solve that.

Comment: [Looping through array and removing items, without breaking for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284)

Answer (score 18):

Here's a function that will remove elements of an array with a particular value that won't fail when two consecutive elements have the same value:

```
function removeElementsWithValue(arr, val) {
    var i = arr.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (arr[i] === val) {
            arr.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

var a = [1, 0, 0, 1];
removeElementsWithValue(a, 0);
console.log(a); // [1, 1]
```

In most browsers (except IE <= 8), you can use the [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method of Array objects, although be aware that this does return you a new array:

```
a = a.filter(function(val) {
    return val !== 0;
});
```

Comment: You could just `return val;` as well

Comment: @BrianLeishman: If all your array members are guaranteed to be numbers then yes, but it's not quite the same in general: using `return val` will filter out any falsy value, such as `false` or an empty string, rather than just `0`.

Comment: Yeah it was specifically in this example, I figured since you had the `!==` that it made sense here

Answer (score 14):

Here's one way to do it:

```js
const array = ['0', '567', '956', '0', '34'];
const filtered = array.filter(Number);

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: >TypeError: 0 is not a function

Answer (score 5):

For ES6 best practice standards:

```
let a = ['0','567','956','0','34'];


a = a.filter(val => val !== "0");
```

(note that your "id's" are strings inside array, so to check regardless of type you should write "!=")

Answer (score 4):

For non-trivial size arrays, it's still vastly quicker to build a new array than splice or filter.

```
var new_arr = [],
tmp;

for(var i=0, l=old_arr.length; i<l; i++)
{
  tmp = old_arr[i];

  if( tmp !== '0' )
  {
    new_arr.push( tmp );
  }
}
```

If you do splice, iterate backwards!

Answer (score 2):

Below code can solve your problem

```
 for(var i=0; i<ids.length;i++ )
 { 
    if(ids[i]=='0')
        ids.splice(i,1); 
  }
```

Comment: its simple and easy to understand, and solves the problem also. thanks

Comment: That will fail if the array has two consecutive zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

```
ids.filter(function(x) {return Number(x);});
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe, the shortest method is

```
var newList = ['0', '567', '956', '0', '34'].filter(cV => cV != "0")
```

You could always do,

```
listWithZeros = ['0', '567', '956', '0', '34']
newList = listWithZeros.filter(cv => cv != "0")
```

The `newList` contains your required list.

**Explanation**

> Array.prototype.filter()

This method returns a new array created by filtering out items after testing a conditional function

It takes in **one** function with possibly **3** parameters.

Syntax:

```
Array.prototype.filter((currentValue, index, array) => { ... })
```

The parameters explain themselves.

[Read more here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0):

The easy approach is using `splice`!!. But there's a problem, every time you remove an element your array size will constantly reduce. So the loop will skip 1 index the array size reduces.

This program will only remove every first zero.

```js
// Wrong approach
let num = [1, 0, 0,  2, 0, 0, 3,];

for(let i=0; i<num.length; i++){
    if(num[i]==0)
        num.splice(i, 1);
}
console.log(num)
```

the output will be

```
[1,0,2,0,3]
```

So to remove all the zeros you should increase the index if you found the non-zero number.

```
let i = 0;
while(i<num.length){
    if(num[i]==0){
        num.splice(i,1);
    }
    else{
        i++;
    }
}
```

But there's a better way. Since changing the size of the array only affects the right side of the array. You can just traverse in reverse and splice.

```
for(let i=num.length-1; i>=0; i--){
    if(num[i]===0)
        num.splice(i,1);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This question is asked more than 9 years ago and it has an accepted answer. The accepted answer also uses `split`. Please add some details about the reason you are adding a new answer.