# Looping through array and removing items, without breaking for loop

Tags: javascript, loops

I have the following for loop, and when I use `splice()` to remove an item, I then get that 'seconds' is undefined.  I could check if it's undefined, but I feel there's probably a more elegant way to do this.  The desire is to simply delete an item and keep on going.

```
for (i = 0, len = Auction.auctions.length; i < len; i++) {
    auction = Auction.auctions[i];
    Auction.auctions[i]['seconds'] --;
    if (auction.seconds < 0) { 
        Auction.auctions.splice(i, 1);
    }           
}
```

Comment: In addition to iterating backwards and adjust length, you can also just put the members you want into a new array.

Comment: Why do you say `Auction.auctions[i]['seconds']--` instead of `auction.seconds--`?

Comment: you probably wanna look into the predefined function .shift();

Answer (score 1081, accepted):

The array is being re-indexed when you do a `.splice()`, which means you'll skip over an index when one is removed, and your cached `.length` is obsolete.

To fix it, you'd either need to decrement `i` after a `.splice()`, or simply iterate in reverse...

```
var i = Auction.auctions.length
while (i--) {
    ...
    if (...) { 
        Auction.auctions.splice(i, 1);
    } 
}
```

This way the re-indexing doesn't affect the next item in the iteration, since the indexing affects only the items from the current point to the end of the Array, and the next item in the iteration is lower than the current point.

Comment: Wondering if `length === 0` would end up in an infinite loop, I have tried this solution and (of course it does work), since it evaluates first the value of `i` and then decrements. However, `--` (and `++`) are so weird in their behaviour that a modern language like swift  stopped supporting them. I think they are bad practise (at least in a such a context).

Comment: @lukas_o There is no weirdness or unexpected functionality if you simply understand what it means. `i++` mean evaluate the value, then increment it. `++i` means increment the value, then evaluate it. JS will never do anything but that. This is really easy to understand, and it's guaranteed to work exactly the same way every time, even if you use a different JS engine.

Answer (score 261):

This is a pretty common issue. The solution is to loop backwards:

```
for (var i = Auction.auctions.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    Auction.auctions[i].seconds--;
    if (Auction.auctions[i].seconds < 0) { 
        Auction.auctions.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter if you're popping them off of the end because the indices will be preserved as you go backwards.

Answer (score 60):

Recalculate the length each time through the loop instead of just at the outset, e.g.:

```
for (i = 0; i < Auction.auctions.length; i++) {
      auction = Auction.auctions[i];
      Auction.auctions[i]['seconds'] --;
      if (auction.seconds < 0) { 
          Auction.auctions.splice(i, 1);
          i--; //decrement
      }
}
```

That way you won't exceed the bounds.

EDIT: added a decrement in the if statement.

Answer (score 57):

Although your question is about deleting elements from **the array being iterated upon** and not about removing elements (in addition to some other processing) efficiently, I think one should reconsider it if in similar situation.

The algorithmic complexity of this approach is `O(n^2)` as splice function and the for loop both iterate over the array (splice function shifts all elements of array in the worst case). Instead you can just push the required elements to the new array and then just assign that array to the desired variable (which was just iterated upon).

```
var newArray = [];
for (var i = 0, len = Auction.auctions.length; i < len; i++) {
    auction = Auction.auctions[i];
    auction.seconds--;
    if (!auction.seconds < 0) { 
        newArray.push(auction);
    }
}
Auction.auctions = newArray;
```

---

Since ES2015 we can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to fit it all in one line:

```
Auction.auctions = Auction.auctions.filter(auction => --auction.seconds >= 0);
```

Answer (score 28):

```
Auction.auctions = Auction.auctions.filter(function(el) {
  return --el["seconds"] > 0;
});
```

Answer (score 24):

If you are e using ES6+ - why not just use `Array.filter` method?

```
Auction.auctions = Auction.auctions.filter((auction) => {
  auction['seconds'] --;
  return (auction.seconds > 0)
})
```

Note that modifying the array element during filter iteration only works for objects and will not work for array of primitive values.

Comment: How do I do that in-place via filter? The variable whose content I'm trying to modify is a read-only property / declared as `const`?

Answer (score 18):

Here is a simple linear time solution to this simple linear time problem.

When I run this snippet, with n = 1 million, each call to filterInPlace() takes .013 to .016 seconds.  A quadratic solution (e.g. the accepted answer) would take a million times that, or so.

```js
// Remove from array every item such that !condition(item).
function filterInPlace(array, condition) {
   var iOut = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
     if (condition(array[i]))
       array[iOut++] = array[i];
   array.length = iOut;
}

// Try it out.  A quadratic solution would take a very long time.
var n = 1*1000*1000;
console.log("constructing array...");
var Auction = {auctions: []};
for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  Auction.auctions.push({seconds:1});
  Auction.auctions.push({seconds:2});
  Auction.auctions.push({seconds:0});
}
console.log("array length should be "+(3*n)+": ", Auction.auctions.length)
filterInPlace(Auction.auctions, function(auction) {return --auction.seconds >= 0; })
console.log("array length should be "+(2*n)+": ", Auction.auctions.length)
filterInPlace(Auction.auctions, function(auction) {return --auction.seconds >= 0; })
console.log("array length should be "+n+": ", Auction.auctions.length)
filterInPlace(Auction.auctions, function(auction) {return --auction.seconds >= 0; })
console.log("array length should be 0: ", Auction.auctions.length)
```

Note that this modifies the original array in place rather than creating a new array; doing it in place like this can be advantageous, e.g. in the case that the array is the program's single memory bottleneck; in that case, you don't want to create another array of the same size, even temporarily.

Comment: this is the correct solution and yet this has 17 votes while the O(n^2) solution has 1000 votes... this industry is dead

Answer (score 15):

Another simple solution to digest an array elements once:

```
while(Auction.auctions.length){
    // From first to last...
    var auction = Auction.auctions.shift();
    // From last to first...
    var auction = Auction.auctions.pop();

    // Do stuff with auction
}
```

Answer (score 15):

The normal for loop is more familiar for me, I just need to decrement the index each time I remove an item from the array

```js
//5 trues , 5 falses
var arr1 = [false, false, true, true, false, true, false, true, true, false];

//remove falses from array
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
    if (arr1[i] === false){
        arr1.splice(i, 1);
        i--;// decrement index if item is removed
    }
}
console.log(arr1);// should be 5 trues
```

Comment: I find this approach (splice and decrement) with *consideration for familiarity* as most portable/understandable when want to cut small edge case out of for-loop without rewriting loop into filter/reduce/flatmap etc or looping backwards (which may not notice 6 months later). The other solutions are better/smarter, but sometimes just need to patch out small loop edge case.

Answer (score 11):

Here is another example for the proper use of splice. This example is about to remove 'attribute' from 'array'.

```
for (var i = array.length; i--;) {
    if (array[i] === 'attribute') {
        array.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why waste cpu cycles on .splice? that operation has to go through the whole loop again and again to remove an element in an array.

why not just use traditional 2 flags in one loop?

```js
const elements = [1, 5, 5, 3, 5, 2, 4];
const remove = 5

i = 0

for(let j = 0; j < elements.length; j++){
  if (elements[j] !== remove) {
    elements[i] = elements[j]
    i++
  }
}
elements.length = i
```

Comment: This code works but for a long list it would be tedious to move all the elements like bubbles

Comment: I don't understand this, can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

Try to relay an array into newArray when looping:

```
var auctions = Auction.auctions;
var auctionIndex;
var auction;
var newAuctions = [];

for (
  auctionIndex = 0; 
  auctionIndex < Auction.auctions.length;
  auctionIndex++) {

  auction = auctions[auctionIndex];

  if (auction.seconds >= 0) { 
    newAuctions.push(
      auction);
  }    
}

Auction.auctions = newAuctions;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two examples that work:

Example ONE

```
// Remove from Listing the Items Checked in Checkbox for Delete
let temp_products_images = store.state.c_products.products_images
if (temp_products_images != null) {
    for (var l = temp_products_images.length; l--;) {
        // 'mark' is the checkbox field
        if (temp_products_images[l].mark == true) {
            store.state.c_products.products_images.splice(l,1);         // THIS WORKS
            // this.$delete(store.state.c_products.products_images,l);  // THIS ALSO WORKS
        }
    }
}
```

Example TWO

```
// Remove from Listing the Items Checked in Checkbox for Delete
let temp_products_images = store.state.c_products.products_images
if (temp_products_images != null) {
    let l = temp_products_images.length
    while (l--)
    {
        // 'mark' is the checkbox field
        if (temp_products_images[l].mark == true) {
            store.state.c_products.products_images.splice(l,1);         // THIS WORKS
            // this.$delete(store.state.c_products.products_images,l);  // THIS ALSO WORKS
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```js
RemoveItems.forEach((i, j) => {
    OriginalItems.splice((i - j), 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## Deleting Parameters

```
        oldJson=[{firstName:'s1',lastName:'v1'},
                 {firstName:'s2',lastName:'v2'},
                 {firstName:'s3',lastName:'v3'}]
        
        newJson = oldJson.map(({...ele}) => {
          delete ele.firstName;
          return ele;
          })
```

it deletes and and create new array and as we are using spread operator on each objects so the original array objects are also remains unharmed

Answer (score 0):

```
    const arr = [...]
    const indexes = [1,2,8,9,34,67]
    
    const result = arr.filter((_, index) => !indexes.includes(index));
    
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

There are lot of wonderful answers on this thread already. However I wanted to share my experience when I tried to solve "remove nth element from array" in ES5 context.

JavaScript arrays have different methods to add/remove elements from start or end. These are:

```
arr.push(ele) - To add element(s) at the end of the array 
arr.unshift(ele) - To add element(s) at the beginning of the array
arr.pop() - To remove last element from the array 
arr.shift() - To remove first element from the array
```

Essentially none of the above methods can be used directly to remove nth element from the array.

> A fact worth noting is that this is in contrast with java iterator's
>   using which it is possible to remove nth element for a collection
>   while iterating.

This basically leaves us with only one array method `Array.splice` to perform removal of nth element (there are other things you could do with these methods as well, but in the context of this question I am focusing on removal of elements):

```
Array.splice(index,1) - removes the element at the index
```

Here is the code copied from original answer (with comments):

```js
var arr = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
var i = arr.length; //initialize counter to array length 

while (i--) //decrement counter else it would run into IndexOutBounds exception
{
  if (arr[i] === "four" || arr[i] === "two") {
    //splice modifies the original array
    arr.splice(i, 1); //never runs into IndexOutBounds exception 
    console.log("Element removed. arr: ");

  } else {
    console.log("Element not removed. arr: ");
  }
  console.log(arr);
}
```

Another noteworthy method is `Array.slice`. However the return type of this method is the removed elements. Also this doesn't modify original array. Modified code snippet as follows:

```js
var arr = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
var i = arr.length; //initialize counter to array length 

while (i--) //decrement counter 
{
  if (arr[i] === "four" || arr[i] === "two") {
    console.log("Element removed. arr: ");
    console.log(arr.slice(i, i + 1));
    console.log("Original array: ");
    console.log(arr);
  }
}
```

Having said that, we can still use `Array.slice` to remove nth element as shown below. However it is lot more code (hence inefficient)

```js
var arr = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
var i = arr.length; //initialize counter to array length 

while (i--) //decrement counter 
{
  if (arr[i] === "four" || arr[i] === "two") {
    console.log("Array after removal of ith element: ");
    arr = arr.slice(0, i).concat(arr.slice(i + 1));
    console.log(arr);
  }

}
```

> The `Array.slice` method is extremely important to achieve
>   immutability in functional programming à la redux

Comment: Note that more code should not be a measure of a code's efficiency.

Comment: @kano - please read above. It actually says, more code is inefficient. For ones, it's inefficient use of developer time writing it.

Answer (score -8):

You can just look through and use [`shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)

Comment: Please add an example using this method.