# Why is the JS Array skipping certain entries when running the splice method within a loop?

Tags: javascript

I have an array:

```
var productIds = new Array("1","6","7","Product-Total","ccFirst","ccLast","email","ccExpMonth","ccExpYear","billingAddress","billingCity","billingState","billingZip");
```

I want to delete a value if it is not a number:

```
for(var i=0; i<productIds.length; i++){
   if(isNaN(Number(productIds[i]))) {  
       productIds.splice(i,1);          
   }
}
```

It seems the splice method is affecting the positions of the values.

I found this solution([Looping through array and removing items, without breaking for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop)) which is what I think I need, but I can't figure out how to implement their answers for my code.

How can I fix my problem?

btw, I posted a more detailed jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fte3m/2/

Comment: After you modify the array - its indexes are recalculated. So after you removed element with index `1` in array of 3 elements - there are elements with `0` and `1`, not `0` and `2`

Comment: Your linked answer has the answer. ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looping through array and removing items, without breaking for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop)

Comment: You can probably use `isNaN(productIds[i])` instead of `isNaN(Number(productIds[i]))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you delete the entry at index `i`, you need to subtract 1 from `i` so the entry that was moved down is not skipped.

```
for(var i=0; i<productIds.length; i++){
   if(isNaN(productIds[i])) {  
       productIds.splice(i--,1);  // <-- Decrement i
   }
}
```

As RobG points out in his comment, it's easier to simply process the array in the other direction:

```
for(var i=productIds.length - 1; i>=0; i--){
   if(isNaN(productIds[i])) {
       productIds.splice(i,1);
   }
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't mind reassigning `productIds` to be a new array object and you are running JS 1.6 or later:

```
productIds = productIds.filter(function (id) {
    return !isNaN(id);
});
```

(Note that in the above, I just use `isNaN(value)` rather than `isNaN(Number(value))`. Whenever `Number(value)` would return `NaN`, `isNaN(value)` will return `true`, and *vice versa*. Note also that neither approach will filter out a `null` id, since `Number(null)==0` and `isNaN(null)==false`. If you want to exclude `null` entries from the result, you will need to test for that separately.)

Comment: Or use a decrementing counter.

Comment: @RobG - Yes, that works well (maybe better) than decrementing `i` in the loop. I think `filter` is more elegant, though. :)