# Removing an element from a javascript array inside a loop

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which iterates through a JS array.  When I get to a specific element, I want to remove it.  I realise that I can use splice, but is there a way that doesn't involve me tracking the index:

```
    myArray.forEach(function (point) {
        canvasContext.clearRect(point.PointX - 3, point.PointY - 3, 6, 6);
        point.PointY++;
        canvasContext.fillRect(point.PointX - 3, point.PointY - 3, 6, 6);

        if (point.PointY > canvas.height) {
            // Remove point

        }
    });
```

Comment: Other great (better?) solutions than the here given ones: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the array in-place can be tricky, so perhaps [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is a better function to use:

```
myArray = myArray.filter(function (point) {
    canvasContext.clearRect(point.PointX - 3, point.PointY - 3, 6, 6);
    point.PointY++;
    canvasContext.fillRect(point.PointX - 3, point.PointY - 3, 6, 6);

    if (point.PointY > canvas.height) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

It returns an array with all elements for which the callback returned `true`.

Comment: Just a heads-up: I think this doesn't work in IE < 9.

Comment: @SimonSteinberger The link has a polyfill for browsers that don't support `.filter()` natively.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 2nd parameter to `forEach`, `index` and `Array.splice`:

```
myArray.forEach(function (point, index) {
    canvasContext.clearRect(point.PointX - 3, point.PointY - 3, 6, 6);
    point.PointY++;
    canvasContext.fillRect(point.PointX - 3, point.PointY - 3, 6, 6);

    if (point.PointY > canvas.height) {
        myArray.splice(index, 1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's often an issue with loops that change the length of the array being looped over. They will end up 'skipping' an item.

It's typical when you're going to affect the length of the array to count down instead of up, with a loop like this:

```
for (var i = Things.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  //your code here
};
```