# Thread-safe array deletions

Tags: javascript

I know one can either `splice` an item out of an array, or delete it with `delete`. The former approach can cause concurrency problems, e.g. if one thread is walking over the array while another has just shifted or spliced. `delete` doesn't have this issue if `forEach` is used on the array, since `forEach` will walk over holes in the array.

However, the array can't keep growing forever and will necessitate sweeping, potentially causing the same issue as in the case of a splice. Sounds like I need locking, but I'd be amused if Javascript had any facilities for it. Any thoughts?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support threads, other than a recent HTML5 feature (and that doesn't allow sharing of arrays)

Comment: Can you show us an example where two "threads" are trying to access an array at the same time? It should be impossible with JavaScript

Comment: [You shell not use `delete` on arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500606/1048572)

Comment: @dystroy: I know it *is* (though [some oddities](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2734025/1048572)), but the OP sounded like he had an actual problem with concurrency…

Comment: Over-thinking a problem that doesn't exist? :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Regarding your precise question: No, you can't have concurrency problem as JavaScript isn't multithreaded. Even if you use webworkers you won't have problems as no data is shared (workers communicate by passing messages). Even in node.js your script isn't multi-threaded. There's no way that a parallel execution does anything during the execution of your function unless you use `await`.

So simply use `splice`, there is no need to lock the array.

Regarding concurrency problems more generally, you should be aware that, as soon as you use `await`, the execution can be cut in chunks and another function can run while you're awaiting. `splice` will never be cut but be careful to the logic of your algorithm on shared data when you're in an `async` function.

Comment: That makes sense in light of `libev` that node.js uses. I should have researched this a bit more before asking this! Thanks.

Comment: With ECMA6, JavaScript is asynchronous with help of Promises. We can create async functions now. So don't  you think that we might need a lock ?

Comment: @JayShah there are some cases where you could have interleaved executions thanks to async/await but not during the execution of a splice statement. If some block of code isn't doing asynchronous calls, it won't be broken and no other user code will be executed at the same time.

Comment: This isn't true. Yes - JS isn't multithreaded. But not being multithreaded doesn't mean you cannot have concurrency problems. Having two concurrent events call a function that loops + splices the same large array at the same time causes an undefined logical flow which could, and often does, lead to overflows. Example problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop

Comment: @aggregate1166877 This function you revived was asked and answered in 2013, before `async`. I edited to precise a potential problem. But your comment is very vague and *"Having two concurrent events call a function"* is misleading as, whatever the model, the calls are sequential and the only parallelism is interleaved chunks of execution in async function.

Comment: My apologies @DenysSéguret, I had a pretty bad bug in a large application that looked like a concurrency issue. After over a week of debugging and not finding the problem, I was now trying to trying to reproduce it in a minimal code example for an SO question when the minimal example suddenly made the issue glaringly obvious. It had nothing to do with event loop concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is singlethreaded so there's no problem.