# Loop through array when removing elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm wondering if and what is a reliable and/or standard way of iterating an array whose length is changing inside the loop. I ask because I end up choosing a different method to do this each time I want to do it, e.g.

```
for ( var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++ ) {
  if (myarray[i] === 'something') {
    myarray.splice(i, 1);

    // *to avoid jumping over an element whose index was just shifted back to the current i
    i--;
  }
}
```

**or**

```
var i = 0;
while (myarray[i]) {
  if (myarray[i] === 'something') {
    myarray.splice(i, 1);
  } else {
    i++;
  }
}
```

These are the ways I find myself doing this, but I'm curious if there is a standard approach.

Comment: Have you checked this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop] answer?

Comment: You could keep your forward iteration in the first example and put your post decrementing `i` directly in the `.splice()` call: `myarray.splice(i--, 1);`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I find simpler to iterate in the other direction :

```
for (var i=myarray.length; i--; ) {
   if (myarray[i] === 'something') myarray.splice(i, 1);
}
```

This way you don't have to change the increment when removing.

Many developers, especially the ones who didn't deal with C-like languages before JavaScript, find it confusing to deal with the subtleties of the decrement operator. The loop I wrote can also be written as

```
for (var i=myarray.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
```

Comment: +1 I asked a similar question in an interview today morning ;-) The best part is even I didn't think of this solution

Comment: This is definitely recommended way to iterate through a collection that will have items removed. I do this in any language.

Comment: @jlafay I've canceled your edit because `for (var i = myarray.length; i > 0; i--) ` doesn't do the same (it starts outside of the array and miss the element at index 0).

Comment: You're right on both points but that also means that your code that sets `i` to `myarray.length` is also wrong. That should be `var i = myarray.length - 1` instead. IMO decrementing the index in the for conditional is a little dirty and that's why I changed that. I should have checked `i >= 0` instead.

Comment: @dystroy I'm curious why i-- > 0 doesn't miss the element at index 0 because it seems like 0 > 0 would return false?

Comment: the result of the i-- expression is the value of i before the decrement.

Comment: @jlafay no, it works. Try this in your console : `for(var i=5; i-->0;) console.log(i)`. You'll see it goes from 4 to 0. This is a frequent and very useful pattern, so it's as simple to just remember it.

Comment: @dystroy so it actually checks if i > 0, and then decrements it, weird, thanks again!

Comment: @jlafay You might prefer the alternate, more readable, version, see edit.

Comment: @dystroy, thanks for further clarifying. I tend to prefer code that's more straight forward because it's more maintainable when others work on the code or if you come back to code after weeks or more away from it.

Comment: I like your first approach - it will only fail when `i === 0` which is a falsey value; but it will decrement after `i` has been evaluated, so will reach 0 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

However you choose to do it, starting in reverse and counting down is simplest. It also depends on whether your array is sparse and if you wish for it to remain sparse. Easiest is to create yourself a reusable function and your own library. You could do this. If you set `compress` to true then your array will become a continuous rather than sparse array. This function will remove all matched occurrences of the value and will return an array of the removed elements.

Javascript

```
function is(x, y) {
    if (x === y) {
        if (x === 0) {
            return 1 / x === 1 / y;
        }

        return true;
    }

    var x1 = x,
        y1 = y;

    return x !== x1 && y !== y1;
}

function removeMatching(array, value /*, compress (default = false)*/ ) {
    var removed = [],
        compress = arguments[2],
        index,
        temp,
        length;

    if (typeof compress !== "boolean") {
        compress = false;
    }

    if (compress) {
        temp = [];
        length = array.length;
        index = 0;
        while (index < length) {
            if (array.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
                temp.push(array[index]);
            }

            index += 1;
        }
    } else {
        temp = array;
    }

    index = 0;
    length = temp.length;
    while (index < length) {
        if (temp.hasOwnProperty(index) && is(temp[index], value)) {
            if (compress) {
                removed.push(temp.splice(index, 1)[0]);
            } else {
                removed.push(temp[index]);
                delete temp[index];
            }
        }

        index += 1;
    }

    if (compress) {
        array.length = 0;
        index = 0;
        length = temp.length;
        while (index < length) {
            if (temp.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
                array.push(temp[index]);
            }

            index += 1;
        }
    }

    return removed;
}

var test = [];

test[1] = 1;
test[50] = 2;
test[100] = NaN;
test[101] = NaN;
test[102] = NaN;
test[200] = null;
test[300] = undefined;
test[400] = Infinity;
test[450] = NaN;
test[500] = -Infinity;
test[1000] = 3;

console.log(test);
console.log(removeMatching(test, NaN));
console.log(test);
console.log(removeMatching(test, Infinity, true));
console.log(test);
```

Output

```
[1: 1, 50: 2, 100: NaN, 101: NaN, 102: NaN, 200: null, 300: undefined, 400: Infinity, 450: NaN, 500: -Infinity, 1000: 3]
[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]
[1: 1, 50: 2, 200: null, 300: undefined, 400: Infinity, 500: -Infinity, 1000: 3]
[Infinity]
[1, 2, null, undefined, -Infinity, 3]
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Mb9XG/)