# Altering the array while an outer loop is still running on that same array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a loop that goes through an array and
[removes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5767325)
some elements from it.

But since it removes the elements from the same array it's looping on, it creates some problems.

Here I have `Players` from which I wanna remove a `player2`

```
Players = [];
Players.push('player1');
Players.push('player2');
Players.push('player2');
Players.push('player2');
Players.push('player3');
Players.push('player2');
Players.push('player2');
Players.push('player2');

function check() {
    for (var i = 0; i < Players.length; i++) {
        if (Players[i] == 'player2')
            kick(Players[i])
    };
}

function kick(player) {
    for (var i = 0; i < Players.length; i++) {
        if (player == Players[i]) {
            Players.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    };
}
```

but

```
check();

console.info(util.inspect(Players));
```

outputs

> `[ 'player1', 'player3', 'player2', 'player2' ]`

What could I do to correct this?

Comment: Why don't you just remove them? `if (Players[i] == 'player2') { delete Players[i]; }`

Comment: see answer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop

Comment: @feeela It makes my array sparse. >[ 'player1', , , , 'player3', , ,  ]

Comment: It's redundant to search for the entry twice. After the first search, you know exactly where the thing is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mind blowing trick: run through the array backwards.

You're hitting the "concurrent modification" scenario (splicing out an element at position i changes the position for all elements after it), so avoid that with:

```
for(i=arr.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
  // ...
  if (shouldberemoved) {
    arr.splice(i,1);
  }
}
```

now you can remove as many elements as you like without affecting the elements preceding it.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you run the loop in reverse order.

```
for (var i = Player.lenght; i < 0; i--)
```

then if you remove, you will not be looking for those elements.