# AngularJS - ng-repeat to assign/generate a new unique ID

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Im using a simple `ng-repeat` to generate a list of countries. Within each list is a hidden row/div that can be expanded and collapsed.

The issue that i am facing, is that before i introduced Angular into my application, i manually hard-coded the element's ID, for example:

```
<li data-show="#country1">
    {{country.name}} has population of {{country.population}}

    <div id="country1">
         <p>Expand/collapse content
    </div>
</li>
<li data-show="#country2">
    {{country.name}} has population of {{country.population}}

    <div id="country2">
         <p>Expand/collapse content
    </div>
</li>
<li data-show="#country3">
    {{country.name}} has population of {{country.population}}

    <div id="country3">
         <p>Expand/collapse content
    </div>
</li>
<li data-show="#country4">
    {{country.name}} has population of {{country.population}}

    <div id="country4">
         <p>Expand/collapse content
    </div>
</li>
```

**New code using `ng-repeat`:**

```
<li ng-repeat="country in countries" data-show="????">
    {{country.name}} has population of {{country.population}}

    <div id="???">
         <p>Expand/collapse content
    </div>
</li>
```

How can i assign a dynamic/incremental id in my `ng-repeat`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use `$index` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

```
<li ng-repeat="country in countries" data-show="????">
    {{country.name}} has population of {{country.population}}

    <div id="country-{{$index}}">
        <p>Expand/collapse content
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks, yup i changed the template syntax.

Comment: in any case, if you are trying to identify a country to show/hide with ng-show, I'd rather add an id in your `countries` object. objects are unordered and using `$index` might not be robust sometimes

Comment: How to change the syntax? very interesting.

Comment: I removed the non-standard {[{ and }]} angular interpolation start and end symbols. This had nothing to do with the question and just made it more complicated and not general purpose. I did this on both the question and this answer. Two of the comments above were in reference to this, sorry if they make no sense now!

Comment: Thanks, while $index may not be robust it seems to be helpful for integration testing - which is why I looked up this option.

Comment: Hi @Iridann, `$index` might not be robust sometimes, e.g. if you modify the array while reading it (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop) what other cases do you have in mind?

Comment: Can anyone please take a look at this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190595/using-infinite-scroll-in-angularjs-and-jade

Answer (score 1):

You may need something like below when you got a nested ng-repeat:

`<label id="country-{{$parent.$index}}-{{$index}}" ng-repeat="city in country.cites">
    {{city.name}}
</label>`

Answer (score 0):

`{{$index+1}}` will show 1-5 for every page of pagination in order to change serial no as per page no of pagination, use `{{$index+curPage*5+1}}`, where curPage is your current page in pagination.