# Using Infinite scroll in angularjs and jade

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pug, nginfinitescroll

I'm using angularjs infinite [scroll](http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/) in my dashboard web app. I have a single page which holds multiple infinite scrollable widgets. Since I want to have an infinite scroll for each of them I decided to use [this](http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/) directive but somehow it's not working as expected. I want the infinite scroll to work relative to the inner content div scrollbar which uses perfect [scrollbar](https://github.com/itsdrewmiller/angular-perfect-scrollbar) instead of main browser window. I have searched on google and found multiple threads explaining 2 new variables which can be used to change the default behavior: **infinite-scroll-container** and **infinite-scroll-parent**. I tried both but none of them is working for me. I think use of perfect-scrollbar is creating the issue.

Jade code:

```
          .hor-col(ng-repeat="stream in socialStreams")
                .box-body(style='min-height: 400px;')
                    perfect-scrollbar.timeline-scroller(wheel-propagation="true" wheel-speed="1" min-scrollbar-length="8" suppressScrollX="true" id="streamScroll-{{$index}}")
                        div(infinite-scroll="loadMorePosts(stream['streamId'], stream['endCursor'])", infinite-scroll-disabled="stream['infiniteScrollDisabled']",  infinite-scroll-container="'#streamScroll-{{$index}}'")
```

Since there are multiple widgets, I can't use same id or class for infinite-scroll-container and therefore decided to generate dynamic id.

How can I inject a dynamic class inside infinite-scroll-container ?

I'm getting following error:

> Error: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document':
>   '#streamScroll-{{$index}}' is not a valid selector.

P.S. I have seen following threads but none of them covered my requirement:

https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll/issues/57

[angularjs infinite scroll in a container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674266/angularjs-infinite-scroll-in-a-container/28521884#28521884)

[AngularJS - ng-repeat to assign/generate a new unique ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264789/angularjs-ng-repeat-to-assign-generate-a-new-unique-id)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure that you need curly braces inside the infinite-scroll-container parameter. You should pass computable string in it, so I'll suggest you to try it like this:

```
infinite-scroll-container="'#streamScroll-' + $index"
```

Cause this parameter, like others, don't need interpolation with curly braces, it is ready to take the expression.

Comment: Awesome! Very glad that it helped.

Answer (score 2):

It is not an actual answer to the problem, but it's worth trying.

I can show you how you can write your own infinite-scroll directive. Here's the code:

HTML

```
<div infinite-scroll="loadSomeData()" load-on="scrollToTop">
...    
</div>
```

The directive:

```
app.directive('infiniteScroll', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
                var raw = element[0];
                element.bind('scroll', function () {
                    if (attrs.loadOn === 'scrollToTop') {
                        if (raw.scrollTop === 0) {
                            $scope.$apply(attrs.infiniteScroll);
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
                            $scope.$apply(attrs.infiniteScroll);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }
 );
```

In the controller of the html:

```
$scope.loadSomeData = function () {
    // Load some data here.
};
```

Notice that `load-on="scrollToTop"` is optional in the html div tag. This is only if you want to execute `loadSomeData()` function when scrolling to top, otherwise it will execute the function when scrolling to the bottom of the div.

Answer (score 1):

Angular material has pretty usefull infinite scroll . I think you should take a look at it [Infinite Scroll](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat)