# fill in ng-model dynamically from JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Here is my sample JSON

```
fields: [
        {
          name: "my_field_name",
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "place holder text"
        }],
```

What I want to do is, dynamically generate form controls depending on the type field and give them ng-model field value as name.

This is how I am generating fields:

```
<div ng-repeat="field in fields">
            <div ng-if="field.type=='text'" class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">{{field.name}}</label>
                    <input type="{{ field.type }}"
                           ng-model="{{ field.name }}"
                                 class="form-control"
                                 required
                                 placeholder="{{ field.placeholder }}"
                    />
            </div> ....other types
```

So in this case my generated value should look like

```
<div ng-repeat="field in fields">
            <div ng-if="field.type=='text'" class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">my_field_name</label>
                    <input type="text"
                           ng-model="my_field_name"
                                 class="form-control"
                                 required
                                 placeholder="{{ field.placeholder }}"
                    />
            </div>
```

But this ng-model attribute does not resolve `{{}}` and I get an error

> Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{ field.name }}] starting at [{ field.name }}]

Is there any way to resolve this?

EDIT:: I figured out! YEY! so there is $index field predefiend in ng-repeat. I could safely use it to create unique ids.
thanks to: [AngularJS - ng-repeat to assign/generate a new unique ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264789/angularjs-ng-repeat-to-assign-generate-a-new-unique-id)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use interpolation braces `{{}}` for `ng-model`. it should point to a property variable

```
ng-model="field.name"
```

Comment: ten ng-model is field.name. I want it to be my_field_name

Comment: Then you need custom directives. Can't use `{{}}` in `ng-model` so you will need to compile the input yourself. Might want to take a look at other dynamic form modules like angular-formly

Answer (score 0):

Try using without interpolation for ng-model

```
<input type="{{ field.type }}" ng-model="field.name" class="form-control" required placeholder="{{ field.placeholder }}"
```

Comment: ten ng-model is field.name. I want it to be my_field_name

Comment: what do you mean by that?