# using slice in angularjs array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

In my angularjs app, i need to manually remove or add old/new data from a data array (service is executed in a loop). For remove, i use slice(); but there is a problem: the item is correctly removed but execVerif_distant(); is not executed for the next item. With my actual code, execVerif_distant(); is executed for each item only half a time. For example, if i need to remove entire array, only half is removed.

```
            // start the loop, search in local datas
            angular.forEach($scope.seaDocument.datas.cages, function(itemLocalCages) {
                execVerif_local(itemLocalCages.url);
            });

            function execVerif_local(identifiant) {
                var iterSearch_local = 0;
                angular.forEach(responseZS, function(itemDistantCages) {
                    if (itemDistantCages.url == identifiant) {
                        iterSearch_local++;
                    }
                });
                // if we not find the local datas in distant datas
                if (iterSearch_local == 0) {
                    // verifItem(); call
                    verifItem('remove', identifiant);
                }
            }




                // verifItem();
                function verifItem(action, url) {
                    if (action == 'remove') {
                        var iIndex = -1;
                        angular.forEach($scope.seaDocument.datas.cages, function(itemLocalCages) {
                            iIndex++;
                            if (itemLocalCages.url == url) {
                                $scope.seaDocument.datas.cages.splice(iIndex,1);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                }
```

what's wrong ?

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9882349/736967

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `foreach` is iterating over the same object you are removing things from. To avoid this behavior clone the object you are iterating *before* the loop and work with them as separate:

```
// ... code
var arrCopy = $scope.seaDocument.datas.cages.slice(); //this will create a deep copy.

angular.forEach(arrCopy, function(itemLocalCages) {
  iIndex++;
  if (itemLocalCages.url == url) {
    $scope.seaDocument.datas.cages.splice(iIndex,1);
  }
});
//... more code
```