# Filter the original array of objects by array of ids

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have two arrays:

**array a:**

```
var a = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'a'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'b'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'c'
  }
];
```

**array ids:**

```
var ids = [1];
```

I want to array a filtered by array ids, result i wanted:

```
var a = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'a'
  }
];
```

The most important thing is i want the change on the original array, rather than return a new array.

underscore solution is better:)

Comment: Side note: check out this META post http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Today I tried to solve similar task (filtering the **original** array of objects without creating a new array) and this is what I came up with:

```
const a = [{ id: 1, name: 'a'}, { id: 2, name: 'b'}, { id: 3, name: 'c'}];
const ids = [1];

Array.from(Array(a.length).keys()).reverse().forEach(index =>
  !ids.some(id => id === a[index].id) && a.splice(index, 1)
);

console.log(a); // [{ id: 1, name: 'a'}]
```

The point is that we need to loop back through the original array to be able to use `Array.prototype.splice`, but I didn't want the for-loop, I wanted to have ES6 one-liner. And `Array.from(Array(a.length).keys()).reverse()` gives me a list of reversed indexes of the original array. Then I want to splice the original array by current index only if the corresponding item's `id` is not present in the `ids` array.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
a = a.filter(function(el){ 
    return ~ids.indexOf(el.id)
});

// should give you [{id: 1, name: 'a'}]
```

Comment: I see, perhaps this answer might be helpful to you then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop

Comment: I did an edit request and all you had to do was replace the variable a with the new array

Comment: first time I see the use of the "~" in a context like this, can you explain what it does?

Comment: @Fabrice see [here](https://wsvincent.com/javascript-tilde/) for an explanation, but I answered this question many years ago, now I would recommend using [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)