# Angular JS - Ionic - delete from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ionic-framework

Hello I am having problems of indexes when trying to delete from an array.

```
 <i class="icon ion-ios-checkmark-outline" ng-click="addToHistory(task.info, task.measured, task.total, task.done, task.id)"  ></i> 
            {{task.info}}
```

```js
 $scope.addToHistory = function(title, measured, total, done, id) {
     var index = $scope.tasksCollection.indexOf($scope.tasksCollection[id]);
     $scope.tasksCollection.splice(index, 1);
}
```

the Above works, but when I try to delete the first item, and go for the second one, the third gets deleted instead of the second one. I know is a problem of indexes, but I dont have ideas on how to solve it.

To recap I have:

- Item1 (index 0)
- Item2 (index 1)
- Item3 (index 2)

when I delete the first one I get

- Item2 (index 0)
- Item3 (index 1)

and when I try to delete Item2, the index I get back is 1, so Item3 gets deleted.

Comment: Appreciate you may be new to SO. If one/any of these are correct, please mark it as such for the benefit of future searchers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is with using the task.id for the lookup.

Try passing in $index instead.

```
<i class="icon ion-ios-checkmark-outline" ng-click="addToHistory($index, task.info, task.measured, task.total, task.done, task.id)"  ></i> 
            {{task.info}}
```

js

```
$scope.addToHistory = function(index, title, measured, total, done, id) {
     $scope.tasksCollection.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Docs for [index](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.tasksCollection[id]
```

Tries to get the task at index id - now depending on how that id is generated, you could either have something like :

```
$scope.tasksCollection[123] - which won't make sense (if it's an actual entity id)
```

or if you set the id property on the client side, once you remove from the collection, the ids won't match.

Use $index for what you want to do like HockeyJ suggested.

Answer (score -1):

This is a problem with using splice in a loop.  Splice reindexes the array and makes length property obsolete.  Generally the solution is to run through the array backwards when deleting. See this previous answer for more help.

[Looping through array and removing items, without breaking for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop)