# Im trying to remove a specified option from a select box in Javascript

Tags: javascript, select

Im trying to remove a selected option from a select box in a function. the code below doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
function removeItem(refundItem) {

    itemToDelete = document.getElementById("yourStuff").options[refundItem].text;
    inCart = document.getElementById("yourCart").rows.length;
    for (i = 1; i <= inCart; i++) {
        maybeRefund = document.getElementById("yourCart").rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML;
        maybeRefund = maybeRefund.trim();
        if (itemToDelete == maybeRefund) {

            refundPrice = document.getElementById("yourCart").rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("yourCart").deleteRow(i);
            Money.value = Number(Money.value) + Number(refundPrice);
            document.getElementById("yourCart").deleteRow(i);
            document.getElementById("yourStuff").options.remove(refundItem);

            //            document.getElementById("yourStuff").options.remove(selectedIndex);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("yourStuff").selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your removing from a list while looping through it. I imagine that may be an issue.

[Looping through array and removing items, without breaking for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop)

Try looping backwards.

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
..
document.getElementById("yourStuff").remove(refundItem);
..
```

i.e remove item with index `refundItem` from select, having id `yourStuff`. See [Select remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/remove) for more info