# splice leave record behind

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why my below code leaving one record? It should delete all 3 record from vm.events if my Id=40

```
vm.events = [
            {
                "studentId": "40",
                "studentName": "P  Arjun",
            },
            {
                "studentId": "40",
                "studentName": "P  Arjun",
            },
            {
                "studentId": "40",
                "studentName": "P  Arjun",
            }
        ];

vm.setSelectedStudent = function (Id) {
            vm.stdListCope = angular.copy(vm.events);
            for (var i in vm.stdListCope) {
               if (vm.stdListCope[i]['studentId'] == Id) {
                    vm.stdListCope.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: @MukeshSharma `splice()` alters original array.

Comment: I tried with vm.stdListCope.pop(); ... but still getting one behind

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping through array and removing items, without breaking for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you are splicing the array while you are browsing it. Thus, you should not increase the index when deleting a row. Here is a corrected version of your code using a while:

```
vm.events = [
            {
                "studentId": "40",
                "studentName": "P  Arjun",
            },
            {
                "studentId": "40",
                "studentName": "P  Arjun",
            },
            {
                "studentId": "40",
                "studentName": "P  Arjun",
            }
        ];

vm.setSelectedStudent = function (Id) {
            vm.stdListCope = angular.copy(vm.events);
            for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
               while (vm.stdListCope[i] != undefined && vm.stdListCope[i]['studentId'] == Id) {
                    vm.stdListCope.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        };
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: it works, but error when I am adding another different studentId. for example {
                "studentId": "41",
                "studentName": "P x Arjun"
            }

Comment: Sorry I made a huge mistake. I edited the code and now it should work. Let me know!

Comment: Glad it helped ! I also edited the code to use `for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)`

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in your code.

When it runs for `i=0`, `vm.stdListCope.splice(0, 1);` slices the array to the array with single entry.

So, after `i=0`, `vm.stdListCope` has `[{"studentId": "40", "studentName": "P  Arjun", }]`

But, when the loop runs for `i=1` or `i =2`, `vm.stdListCope[i]['studentId'] == Id` won't be true, because there is not entry corresponding to index `i=1` and `i=2` as it has length = 1.

That's why you are left with only 1 entry.