# how to remove javascript array element?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects and I am removing elements based on object value, without knowing which element it is.

So... those lovely people who flagged my question as duplicate and suggest I read [How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript) are not helping.

My question... again...

*I have an array of objects*

- I want to search and remove specific elements from the array. I have a solution that is long winded (loop thru the array once, make a list of element id's, then slice one by one in another loop). I am hoping there is another method (enhance my skillset too).

  ```
  myarray.filter(function(item)
  {
      if( item.flag==="Y" )
      {
          // how to delete element from myarray
          // delete implies remove it from myarray
      }
  });
  ```

All help appreciated =)

Comment: `myarray = myarray.filter(function(item) { return item.flag!=="Y"  });`

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, Dupe is invalid in the context of this question!

Comment: You both are right... from what I recall too, it is how I first discovered the "filter" array method. Thank you

Comment: @RayonDabre why? The solutions given here are already in the linked question. They could have easily been found with a little search.

Comment: You can also check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop/9882349#9882349](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop/9882349#9882349)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes

Comment: The answers are already here - you're just using `filter` incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two options:

#### Create a *new* array with `filter`

The first is to create a new array containing only the entries you want. You're already on the right track with `filter`:

```
myArray = myArray.filter(function(item) {
    return item.flag !== "Y";
});
```

The new array will only have the entries that the callback returned a truthy value for. In this case, only ones whose `flag` is `!== "Y"`. Entries whose `flag` is `=== "Y"` will be left out of it.

Note that if you have *other* references to this same array in other variables, they will continue to point to the **old** array. Only `myArray` (in the above) gets a reference to the **new** array.

#### Modify the *existing* array with `splice` and a loop

The second is to use a `while` loop and `splice`:

```
var n = 0;
while (n < myArray.length) {
    if (myArray[n].flag === "Y") {
        // Remove it
        myArray.splice(n, 1);
    } else {
        // Move to next
        ++n;
    }
}
```

Note we don't move to next if we remove one, because we need to test the one after it (which is now at the previous index).

Or as [Nina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz) points out in a comment, a `for` loop going backward:

```
for (var n = myArray.length - 1; n >= 0; --n) {
    if (myArray[n].flag === "Y") {
        // Remove it
        myArray.splice(n, 1);
    }
}
```

In that case, since we're modifying the array (not creating a new one), the changes will be visible through any reference to that same array, not just `myArray`. (Since they all point to the same object, which we modified the state of.)

Comment: you could go backwards, then decrement is always right.

Comment: @NinaScholz: Indeed!

Comment: Thanks for this - the first answer will do me nicely... I will accept it in 7 minutes (I'm told I cannot accept it before then)

Comment: you could also exchange the for loop with `var n = myArray.length; while (n--) { ... }`...

Comment: @NinaScholz: Yeah. I'm not a huge fan of that kind of thing. But it would absolutely work.

Answer (score 0):

**Remove object in array by its property-value:**

Remove value: 30:

```
arr.splice(arr.map(el => el.value).indexOf(30), 1);
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/76eL1bhw/)

Remove name: "John":

```
arr.splice(arr.map(el => el.name).indexOf("John"), 1);
```