# How to delete item in JSON file

Tags: json, node.js

Hi Im trying to delete an object in a JSON file but it isnt working. I set the value p equal to the entire item which includes the values name, date and number. When I use delete in order to delete the specific item from the json file it doesn't get deleted. I was wondering if any of you knew why. Thanks.

here is the nodejs code

```
app.get('/testtwilio3', function(req,res,next){

        var fs = require('fs');
      var configFile = fs.readFileSync('./Public/patients.json');
      var config = JSON.parse(configFile);
        var p = {name: req.query.name, date: req.query.date, number: req.query.number};
        var key = p;
        console.log(p);
        delete config[key];
        console.log( config);
    });
```

Here is the code from the controller

```
 $scope.deleteName = function($index){

  var patient = {
            name: $scope.patients[$index].name,
            date: $scope.patients[$index].date,
            number:$scope.patients[$index].number
        }
 $http.get('/testtwilio3', {params: {name: patient.name, number: patient.number, date: patient.date}}) // PASS THE DATA AS THE SECOND PARAMETER
    .success(
        function(success){
          alert("work");
            console.log(success)
        })
    .error(
        function(error){

            console.log("error" + error)
        });


   }
```

Here is the json file

```
[{"name":"John","date":"12/22/2016","number":"781314454"},{"name":"Joe","date":"09/15/2016","number":"7892834640"},{"name":"Mike","date":"08/25/2016","number":"6472329224"},{"name":"Mark","date":"08/06/2016","number":"7819231279"}]
```

Here is what the console is displaying. First line is what I want to be deleted and the lines below it is the array of items.

```
{ name: 'Mark', date: '08/06/2016', number: '7819231279' }

[ { name: 'John', date: '12/22/2016', number: '781314454' },
  { name: 'Nikhilesh Singh',
    date: '09/15/2016',
    number: '7892834640' },
  { name: 'Mike', date: '08/25/2016', number: '6472329224' },
  { name: 'Mark', date: '08/06/2016', number: '7819231279' } ]
```

This is how I want it to be where the item in the first line has been removed form the list of items

```
{ name: 'Mark', date: '08/06/2016', number: '7819231279' }

[ { name: 'John', date: '12/22/2016', number: '781314454' },
  { name: 'Nikhilesh Singh',
    date: '09/15/2016',
    number: '7892834640' },
  { name: 'Mike', date: '08/25/2016', number: '6472329224' } ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDITED]

The [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator is only for deleting a property from an *object*. Your `config` variable contains an *array* of objects, so `delete` will not do what you want at all.

You need to iterate through the `config` array and use something like [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to delete the array items that have the same `name`, `date`, and `number` values as in the request.

[This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop) might be helpful.

Comment: Please provide in your question: the contents of `./Public/patients.json`, what you are actually getting back in your console log, and what you are expecting the result to look like. Without that info, I had to make a lot of guesses. as to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can only delete a single attribute with `delete` (e.g. `delete <attrName>`). If you want to delete multiple attributes you can use lodash's `omit` for example.

Hope this helps.