# Pass in parameters to delete - flutter

Tags: json, flutter, http-delete

I have seen documentation around it only shows how to delete using url but it doesn't show how to pass in parameters to delete only that specific item in the json array?

Calling the delete function:

```
  main() {
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.delete( '35.186.145.243', 8080, '/users');
    httpClient.close();
    return "Success";
  }
```

Parameters that need to be passed in are:

1. String `user_id`
2. String `price`

JSON array:

```
{
    "user_id": "user2",
    "price": "$34"
}
```

Comment: take a look at this related post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38779088/how-to-delete-item-in-json-file?rq=1

Comment: yeah.. is there any other way to delete json array items by passing in parameters?

Comment: it accepts body delete!

Comment: so do not use `delete` method: use [HttpClientRequest](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-io/HttpClientRequest-class.html) and build your http delete request "by hand" instead

Comment: do i change everything to use httpclientrequest?

Comment: i have no idea what you mean by that - did you try `HttpClientRequest`? does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Found out the answer using HTTP client request when using delete on body method!

```
main() async {
    String url = "http://35.186.145.243:8080/users";

    Map map = {
      'price': '$34',
      'user_id': 'user2'
    };

    print(await apiRequest(url, map));
  }

  Future<String> apiRequest(String url, Map jsonMap) async {
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    HttpClientRequest request = await httpClient.deleteUrl(Uri.parse(url));
    request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');
    request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(jsonMap)));

    HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
    String statusCode = response.statusCode.toString();
    String reply = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
    responseMessage = statusCode;

    print(statusCode);

    httpClient.close();
    return reply;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem and the only way to Solve it was to use http client :

```
Future<String> apiRequest() async {
    Map<String, dynamic> Object;
      Object= {
             'price': '$34',
             'user_id': 'user2'
              };
    final client = http.Client();
    try {
      final response = await client.send(http.Request("DELETE", Uri.parse("35.186.145.243:8080"))
        ..headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
        ..body = json.encode(Object));
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    } finally {
      client.close();
    }
  }
```