# gained id is not working in some cases

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this script to find out IDs of elements in a class and then delete them

```
var ids = [];
var eic = document.getElementsByClassName('classname');
for(var i = 0, length = eic.length; i < length; i++) {
    ids.push(eic[i].id);
    $('#'+eic[i].id).remove(); 
}
```

The problem is that when I am trying to delete them, it deletes only some of the elements and the console is returning an error:

> "TypeError: eic[i] is undefined"

When I am not trying to delete them, no error is returned and when I alert gained IDs there is every single one.

Comment: Provide the html source - jsfiddle/snippet/codepen/something...

Comment: are those elements nested?

Comment: Well if you delete elements then the array gets shorter and you end up looping farther than the array's new length.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping through array and removing items, without breaking for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop)

Comment: There are easier ways to iterate a nodelist. While a for loop is faster, you can run into out of bounds issues. With ES6 syntax you can get fancy and spread it (`[...document.querySelectorAll(".classname"].forEach/map/etc`) but I suggest you use `eic.forEach` instead.

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery and DOM?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it is working

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var ids = [];
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".example").each(function(){
            ids.push(this.id);
            $(this).remove();
        });
        $("#resultArray").text(ids);
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Populate array</button>

<div class="example" id="div1">First div element with class="example".</div>

<div class="example" id="div2">Second div element with class="example".</div>

<div class="example" id="div3">Third div element with class="example".</div>

<br>
Array of Ids : <div id="resultArray"><div>
```