# Javascript Photoshop delete paths one by one bug?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

Photoshop CC 2017. Using this loop to delete paths one by one results in some paths (out of 8) being deleted only:

```
 for(i = 0; i < app.activeDocument.pathItems.length; i++) {
             alert(i)
             app.activeDocument.pathItems[i].remove();
        }
```

The length gets reported as being 8. However alert(i) only shows 4 times. All the paths get removed only if running the loop multiple times. I'm deleting them one by one because I want to keep a path with a certain name. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping through array and removing items, without breaking for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop)

Comment: Basically, you are removing an item, which decrements the `.length`. You also increment the `i`, so by the time your `i` = 4, you only have 4 items left in your array, so it is finished.

Comment: Thank you Ivar, that's the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing `pathItems` as you loop through it. When you delete item `i` there will be a new item at position `i` that you skip.
If you do the loop backwards it won't cause any problems

```
 for(i = app.activeDocument.pathItems.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
    alert(i)
    app.activeDocument.pathItems[i].remove();
 }
```

Comment: Yes this also works. I also discovered using Ivar's comment I can loop through the array backwards. I believe using the while loop to delete the [0] element will cause problems if I want to keep a certain element(with a certain name).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pathItems.removeAll()` in this case.

Comment: I'm deleting them one by one because I want to keep a path with a certain name.