# splice not removing element from array

Tags: javascript, splice

I am using splice to remove an element from an array, but it's not working.
as far as I know, the code looks okay , but maybe I am missing/overseeing something.
please take a look. here 'state' is an array containing objects.

```
 let removeFromState = state;
            for(var i=0;i<removeFromState.length;i++){
                if(removeFromState[i].index===action.index){
                    removeFromState.splice[i,1];
                }
            }
            return removeFromState;
```

I cant believe, i was being so silly.
and i had been looking at it for quite a while but didnt see it right in front of me. but I am glad i posted it here, because of the remarks about missing entries because I was increasing 'i' even though I was removing entries.

Comment: Use `()` instead of `[]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looping through array and removing items, without breaking for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. A typo, you're using `[i,1]` (square brackets) where you should be using `(i,1)` (parentheses). Square brackets are property accessors. (The reason this isn't a syntax error is that JavaScript has a *comma operator*, and `[i,1]` evaluates to `[1]`. The reason it's not a runtime error is that `functionname[1]` looks up the property `"1"` on the function — and then disregards any value it finds.)
2. Your loop will skip entries after the entries it removes, because you both remove the entry *and* increase `i`. So when you remove entry #5, entry #6 becomes #5 — but then you move on to `i == 6`. So you never look at the new entry #5.

To fix #2, either only increase `i` if you *don't* remove the entry, or loop backward.

So either:

```
var i = 0;
while (i < removeFromState.length) {
    if(removeFromState[i].index === action.index) {
        removeFromState.splice(i, 1);
    } else {
        ++i;
    }
}
```

or

```
for (var i = removeFromState.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    if(removeFromState[i].index === action.index) {
        removeFromState.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Or alternately, create a *new* array containing only the entries you want to keep:

```
var newArray = removeFromState.filter(function(entry) { return entry.index !== action.index; });
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. specially for point 2 as I didnt see it coming. yeah, i could be missing entries. so, doing i-- instead of i++ should fix that right?

Comment: @faraz: I've added some examples to the end of the answer.

Comment: Thanks. very helpful

Comment: Thanks, I never even spotted the typo in my code, it was driving me nuts

Answer (score 3):

I was stuck on the problem for couple of hours. I did figure out that when you splice an array it does returns the element that was spliced from the original array.

```
let  originalArray = ["Apples","Oranges","Kiwi"];
let newArray = originalArray.splice(0,1);
console.log(newArray);
```

I was expecting the modified originalArray in the spliced variable but instead it returns the element that was spliced.
The answer was to

```
console.log(originalArray);
```

Whatever splice returns, we might not need that, we need to check our originalArray since it's the one that got sliced.
The originalArray consists my expected answer which was ["Oranges","Kiwi"]

Comment: How it that relevant to the question? OP is not saving the result of splice anywhere. And [this behavior is clearly documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Answer (score 2):

`splice` is a method, you call it with parentheses, not square brackets. Square brackets are for indexing (JavaScript is just excessively relaxed and silently returns `undefined` when you "index" the method). Try:

```
removeFromState.splice(i, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Mistake was: you used square brackets instead of parenthesis

```js
function remove(state, action) {
  let removeFromState = state;

  for (var i = 0; i < removeFromState.length; i++) {
    if (removeFromState[i].index === action.index) {
      removeFromState.splice(i, 1);
      i--;    // After deleting, counter reduced
    }
  }
  return removeFromState;
}

console.log(remove([{index: 3}, {index: 3}, {index: 3}], {index: 3}));
```

Comment: Neither you need while, nor complex for loop, just reduce counter when deleting!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you are calling `splice`, it is a function and needs to be called like `splice(i, 1)`

You could simplify the function as below

```
let removeFromState = state;
const findEntry = entry => entry.index === action.index;
removeFromState.splice(removeFromState.findIndex(findEntry), 1);
return removeFromState;
```

Answer (score -1):

`removeFromState` is instantiated as a let constant and therefore not mutable. It should work if `let removeFromState` is changed to `var removeFromState` (.

Comment: `let` doesn't make it a constant.