# How to remove all values of an array with the index specified by the values of another array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

Simple question, but I can´t get over it...

I have two arrays:

```
var arrayA = [67.98, "-", 91.77, "-", "-", 8.09];
var arrayB = [3, 4, 9, 1, 12, 77];
```

So, I need to remove all values from arrayB which have the indexes of the value `"-"` in `arrayA`. In this case the result of arrayB should be:

```
arrayB = [3, 9, 77]
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Array.filter()` on `arrayB`, and preserve items that their respective item in `arrayA` is not a dash:

```js
var arrayA = [67.98, "-", 91.77, "-", "-", 8.09];
var arrayB = [3, 4, 9, 1, 12, 77];

var result = arrayB.filter(function(_, i) {
  return arrayA[i] !== '-';
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Works perfect. I first tried an approach with a for loop, likewise to the comment below, but I think this is much easier, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var arrayA = [67.98, "-", 91.77, "-", "-", 8.09];
    var arrayB = [3, 4, 9, 1, 12, 77];
    
    for (var i = arrayB.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (arrayA[i] == "-") { 
            arrayB.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    
    console.log(arrayB);
```

See: [Looping through array and removing items, without breaking for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop)