# JavaScript not resetting a variable in a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

would like to ask for reason, why JavaScript doesn't reset a variable
after every iteration of the loop, in situation when I try to set it equal to a function argument(#1).
It does the reset, if the variable is equaled to a specific array(#2).

```
#1
    function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
            for (var i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
                var testArray=sequence;
                testArray.splice(i, 1);
                console.log(testArray);
            }
        }
        almostIncreasingSequence([1, 3, 2, 1]);
#2
    function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
            for (var i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
                var testArray=[1, 3, 2, 1];
                testArray.splice(i, 1);
                console.log(testArray);
            }
        }
        almostIncreasingSequence([1, 3, 2, 1]);
```

Will be grateful for every answer. Thank you.

Comment: because `splice` modifies the array in place.

Comment: Your `var testArray=sequence` isn't creating a new array but just referencing sequence. So when you splice testArray you are also splicing sequence. If you want it to reset then you need `var testArray = sequence.slice()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping through array and removing items, without breaking for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop)

Comment: @MohammadUsman His issue isn't understanding that splicing removes the index while the loop proceeds causing the occasional skipped index. His issue is not understanding variable assignment(s) and what passes a reference and what passes a value. Please remove or update your comment.

Comment: If that answer was helpful can you mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the comment above is that you have confusion with your variable assignment.

In #1 you are under the impression that `var testArray = sequence;` is the same as saying `var testArray = [1, 3, 2, 1]`. This isn't the case. `var testArray = sequence` is simply a reference to sequence. Whatever you modify in `testArray` calls back to `sequence` and modifies it there as well.

To fix #1 to perform as #2 you will have to do `var testArray = sequence.slice()`. This performs a shallow copy of `sequence` so that modifying `testArray` has no impact on `sequence`.

```js
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
  for (var i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
      var testArray=sequence.slice();
      testArray.splice(i, 1);
      console.log(testArray);
  }
}

almostIncreasingSequence([1, 3, 2, 1]);
```