# Typescript way to slice elements from array while looping over it

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

What is the typescript way to slice elements from an array while looping over all its elements? Obviously, I want to take into account that the array is re-indexed at every splice.

As stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop) the javascript way of doing this would be:

```
var i = array.length
while (i--) {
    ...
    if (...) { 
        array.splice(i, 1);
    } 
}
```

Unfortunately, the typescript `for (let item of array) {}` loops from 0 to array.length-1 instead of the other way around like the js function above. Splicing an element in this loop would result in one item being skipped.

Comment: Typescript is a superset of JS. It should work.

Comment: do you have a requirement to not create a new array? The correct way (in es6) would be to filter the array, which will create a new one with the elements you want.

Comment: @A.Llorente The sliced array must remain the original array (in my case, it contains objects in a datastore). However, creating a local copy of the array and looping through that copy would allow me to splice the original array without side effects.

Comment: The question is why would you want to alter the array? You can filter the original array and return only the elements that meet your if condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understood from your answers what you need is to filter the array:

```
const filteredArray = array.filter(element => {
    if (yourConditionIsTrue) { // if this element should be in the filteredArray
        return true;
    } else {
        return false
    }
});
```

Which can be done in one line:

```
const filteredArray = array.filter(element => conditionIsTrue);
```

This way your array remains untouched and you get a new array (filteredArray) only with the elements you need, but you don't mess up with the array you are iterating.

Comment: from the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) it seems like I can just write: `array = array.filter(element => yourCondition)`. Correct? You'll notice I keep the same `reference` which is in fact what I meant above (sorry for unclarity).

Comment: Yes indeed you could do it in one liner, if your function returns true the element is added, if it returns false it will not, I will update my answer because it was not clear enough