# Javascript how to remove parameter from URL sting by value?

Tags: javascript, regex, url, url-rewriting

How to remove parameters with `value = 3` from URL string?

Example URL string:

```
https://www.example.com/test/index.html?param1=4&param2=3&param3=2&param4=1&param5=3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are targeting browsers that support [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) you can loop over the URL's `searchParams` object, check each parameter's value, and [delete()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/delete) as necessary. Finally using URL's `href` property to get the final url.

```js
var url = new URL(`https://www.example.com/test/index.html?param1=4&param2=3&param3=2&param4=1&param5=3`)

//need a clone of the searchParams
//otherwise looping while iterating over
//it will cause problems
var params = new URLSearchParams(url.searchParams.toString());
for(let param of params){
   if(param[1]==3){
     url.searchParams.delete(param[0]);
   }
}
console.log(url.href)
```

Comment: Thanks! I think it is better than regular expression.

Comment: @mr.boris see updated example, iterating over it and deleting at the same time will cause it to skip entries so you have to make a clone first and loop over the clone to prevent this problem (it is similar to iterating over [arrays and deleting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop))

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression `replace`. Split off the query string and then `.replace` `&`s (or the initial `^`) up until `=3`s:

```js
const str = 'https://www.example.com/test/index.html?param1=4&param2=3&param3=2&param4=1&param5=3';
const [base, qs] = str.split('?');
const replacedQs = qs.replace(/(^|&)[^=]+=3\b/g, '');
const output = base + (replacedQs ? '?' + replacedQs : '');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Your output still shows `param5=3`.  I though the OP wanted to remove this.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Actually, your answer is little bit [incorrect](https://regex101.com/r/It5qAQ/1)

Comment: @mr.boris My mistake, think I fixed it now

Comment: Your solution still has a problem, because if _all_ the query parameters have a value of 3, it would still leave a dangling `?` at the end of the URL.  [See here](http://rextester.com/MWF82876).

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this with a single regex, using some magic, but I believe that would require using lookbehinds, which most JavaScript regex engines mostly don't yet support.  As an alternative, we can try splitting the query string, then just examining each component to see if the value be `3`. If so, then we remove that query parameter.

```js
var url = "https://www.example.com/test/index.html?param1=4&param2=3&param3=2&param4=1&param5=3";
var parts = url.split(/\?/);
var params = parts[1].replace(/^.*\?/, "").split(/&/);
var param_out = "";
params.forEach(function(x){
    if (!/.*=3$/.test(x))
        param_out += x;
});

url = parts[0] + (param_out !== "" ? "?" + param_out : "");
console.log(url);
```

Comment: thank you. I think it is most supported method for browsers!