# How to remove all the numbers from an array?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove all the numbers from an array. The loop works exactly as I want, but the splice() method still skips some elements for some reason.

```
let arr = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', 'notanumber', '6'];

for (let element of arr) {
  let index = arr.indexOf(element);
  let check = isNaN(element);
  if (check === false) {
    arr.splice(index, 1);
  };
};

console.log(arr);
```

Expected output is: `['notanumber']`
Current output is:  `['2', '4', 'notanumber']`

Comment: You are simultaneously changing the array while you are looping thorough it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping through array and removing items, without breaking for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop)

Answer (score 6):

This would do

```
arr = arr.filter(x => isNaN(x));
```

The problem with calling `splice` for each element is that you're changing the array while iterating over it.

To do what `filter` does by hand the approach should be more like:

```
let wp = 0;
for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if (isNaN(arr[i])) arr[wp++] = arr[i];
}
arr.length = wp;
```

In other words you keep a "write pointer" `wp` and for each element of the array that you want to keep you move it in place, without moving subsequent elements that still need to be processed. Only at the end you resize the result. This is much faster (o(N) instead of o(N²)) and simpler to keep correct.

This second approach moreover will mutate the array inplace, `filter` instead will return a new array and this is different if other references to the array are present in the program.

Comment: this creates a new array and not mutate the old one.

Comment: @NinaScholz: true, added a note about it

Answer (score 3):

Use this as it uses a filter which is less code than a loop:

```js
let arr = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', 'notanumber', '6'];
console.log(arr.filter(x => isNaN(x)))
```

Comment: This KEEPS what is not a number

Comment: @6502 Exactly, OP wants to remove numbers

Comment: @VFDan you misunderstand, your code will keep all the characters that are NaN. OP wants the opposite of that

Comment: Am I going crazy here? The snippet OP has specifically says `// expected output is ['notanumber']` which is what this answer provides...

Comment: @Frontear Read chevybow's comment above.

Answer (score 2):

Why not iterate from the end?

BTW, you need the index, because you search for an index with a value, this goes wrong, if you have more than one same value in the array.

Then you have the problem by iterating from start, because splicing makes, in this case, the array length shorter and the next index is the actual index.

```js
let array = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', 'notanumber', '6'],
    i = array.length;

while (i--) {
    if (!isNaN(array[i])) array.splice(i, 1);
}

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to remove all the numbers like that

```
let arr = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', 'notanumber', '6'];
arr  = arr.filter( element=> isNaN(parseInt(element)) )
console.log(arr); //output is ['notanumber']
```

using the parseInt function in an element that is not number
the return will be [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)

so we can use the filter to remove only the numbers