# How to use splice() method in a 'for...of' loop?

Tags: typescript, for-loop, splice

I want to use splice() with a 'for...of' loop.

Here is what I want to do but with a regular 'for' loop:

```
let celebritiesResult = JSON.parse(celebrityRecognitionJSONFile);
let celebritiesMap = {}
const timestampTolerance = 1000;
const confidenceTolerance = 90;
for (let j = 0; j < celebritiesResult.length;) {
    let celebrity = celebritiesResult[j];
    let prevCelebrity = celebritiesMap[celebrity.Celebrity.Name];
    if ((!prevCelebrity || celebrity.Timestamp - prevCelebrity.Timestamp > timestampTolerance) && celebrity.Celebrity.Confidence > confidenceTolerance) {
        celebritiesMap[celebrity.Celebrity.Name] = celebrity;
        j++;
    } else {
        celebritiesResult.splice(j, 1);
    }
}
```

When I do the same using a 'for...of' loop:

```
let celebritiesResult = JSON.parse(celebrityRecognitionJSONFile);
let celebritiesMap = {}
const timestampTolerance = 1000;
const confidenceTolerance = 90;
let count = 0;
for (let celebrity of celebritiesResult) {
    let prevCelebrity = celebritiesMap[celebrity.Celebrity.Name];
    if ((!prevCelebrity || celebrity.Timestamp - prevCelebrity.Timestamp > timestampTolerance) && celebrity.Celebrity.Confidence > confidenceTolerance) {
        celebritiesMap[celebrity.Celebrity.Name] = celebrity;
        count++;
    } else {
        celebritiesResult.splice(count, 1);
    }
}
```

It doesn't work as expected, the 'splice()' function doesn't remove all elements expected to be removed.

I managed to make the 'for...of' loop work, by creating a second object 'celebritiesResult2' as a clone of 'celebritiesResult' and applying the 'splice()' (method on it):

```
let celebritiesResult = JSON.parse(celebrityRecognitionJSONFile);
let celebritiesResult2 = JSON.parse(celebrityRecognitionJSONFile);//<-
let celebritiesMap = {}
const timestampTolerance = 1000;
const confidenceTolerance = 90;
let count = 0;
for (let celebrity of celebritiesResult) {
    let prevCelebrity = celebritiesMap[celebrity.Celebrity.Name];
    if ((!prevCelebrity || celebrity.Timestamp - prevCelebrity.Timestamp > timestampTolerance) && celebrity.Celebrity.Confidence > confidenceTolerance) {
        celebritiesMap[celebrity.Celebrity.Name] = celebrity;
        count++;
    } else {
        **celebritiesResult2.splice(count, 1);//<-
    }
}
```

The same happens with 'foreach()' too. I have also to create a second object and apply the 'splice()' method on it, so it works as expected.

```
let celebritiesResult = JSON.parse(celebrityRecognitionJSONFile);
let celebritiesResult2 = JSON.parse(celebrityRecognitionJSONFile);//<-
let celebritiesMap = {};
const timestampTolerance = 1000;
const confidenceTolerance = 90;
celebritiesResult.forEach((item, index) => {
    let celebrity = item;
    let prevCelebrity = celebritiesMap[celebrity.Celebrity.Name];
    if ((!prevCelebrity || celebrity.Timestamp - prevCelebrity.Timestamp > timestampTolerance) && celebrity.Celebrity.Confidence > confidenceTolerance) {
        celebritiesMap[celebrity.Celebrity.Name] = celebrity;
    } else {
        celebritiesResult2.splice(index, 1);//<-
    }
});
```

Why?

---

**EDIT**

---

What I don't understand actually, is why the regular `for` loop works and other don't! If we consider what is explained in the link marked as duplicate ([Looping through array and removing items, without breaking for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop)), the `for` loop should be wrong to, and it's not. Why I cannot do the same with a `for...of` loop!?!?!?

Comment: Why do you want to use `for..of`? If it works with an indexed for loop, use an indexed for loop. Basically, you're mutating the array you're iterating over, which leads to exactly these kinds of problems.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I prefer the `for...of`syntax. I just want to understand to avoid similar issues in further developments. The regular `for` loop has been created by another guy, and I had the feeling it was not accurate, so I wanted to verify it by doing the same stuff in my own way.

Answer (score 1):

None of your examples will work correctly, including `for in` loop, because you are modifying number of items in the array, while iterating. Look at the result of simplified `for-in` example:

```js
let array  = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
for (let j = 0; j < array.length;j++) {
 if (j % 2 === 0) {
   array.splice(j, 1);
  }
}
console.log(array);
```

Cleanest approach is, instead of modifying source array, to create new result:

```js
let array  = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

let result = array.filter((item, index) => {
 return index % 2 === 0 ? false : true;
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: In the third and forth example, I am not modifying the same array used for the loop. Are you sure they are not working as expected?

Comment: These are almost identical to answers in the proposed duplicate...

Comment: @118218 I understood you implied that your `for-in` loop works, but `for-of` does not, while neither of those 2 works. Examples with copy (3rd and 4th) probably work, but then you don't need all the extra logic, when you can just filter then.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have looked at proposed duplicate now. There is one answer with `filter` at 5th place. I think this answer is more tailored to what was asked here. It is also more general (no `Auctions.auctions.filter...`) and runnable with clear result.