# How to remove specific value from map

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a map like this:

and I want to remove `{frequency:"WN"}` from array inside map value.

I am trying to remove it this way but value isn't getting removed:

```js
const map2 = new Map();
map2.set(0, [{frequency:"DN"},{frequency:"WN"}, {frequency:"KK"}]);
map2.set(1, [{frequency:"DN"},{frequency:"WN"}, {frequency:"KK"}]);

const strNanFrq = ['DN', 'WN', 'MN', 'QN', 'YN'];
for (tsRequest of map2.values()) {
  tsRequest.filter((req, index) => {
    if (strNanFrq.includes(req['frequency'])) {
      tsRequest.splice(index, 1);
    }
  });
}

console.log(Array.from(map2.values())); // still has all the values in map
```

Comment: If the `frequency` is included in the `strNanFrq` array you want to remove tight? So, `frequency:"DN"}` should also be removed?

Comment: This *should* work. Could someone make a snippet?

Comment: @JonasWilms `splice` on the same array as `filter` might not work

Comment: @adiga yes if it matches then remove

Comment: @adiga not sure why it shouldn't ... Snippet?

Comment: @JonasWilms created. The value still has `WN`. It's the same issue as this:  [Looping through array and removing items, without breaking for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284) After the splice, `{frequency:"WN"}` will be at index = 0 and it is skipped

Comment: @adiga ah, right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the `Map` and `filter` each value to remove the objects with `frequency` included in the `strNanFrq`. Create a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for `strNanFrq` and check if the set [`has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) the current object's frequency.

```js
const map = new Map([
  [0, [{ frequency:"DN" },{ frequency:"WN" }, { frequency:"KK" } ]],
  [1, [{ frequency:"YN" },{ frequency:"AA" }, { frequency:"BB" } ]],
]);

const strNanFrq = new Set(['DN', 'WN', 'MN', 'QN', 'YN']);

for (const [key, value] of map)
  map.set(key, value.filter(v => !strNanFrq.has(v.frequency)))

console.log(map.get(0))
console.log(map.get(1))
```

Answer (score -1):

Set again the map value with a filtered array of the previous array.
If there are more array in the map just use forEach to loop through maps key-value pairs and check if the value is actually an array and reset it with filter:

```js
var map2 = new Map();

map2.set(0, [{frequency:"DN"},{frequency:"WN"}, {frequency:"KK"}]);
map2.set(1, [{frequency:"DN"},{frequency:"WN"}, {frequency:"KK"}]);


map2.forEach((val, key) => {  
  if (Array.isArray(val)) {
      map2.set(key, val.filter(el => el.frequency !== 'WN'));
  }
});

console.log(map2.values());
```

Comment: I may have more number of keys

Comment: You can have more arrays which contain objects with property `frequency` and want to remove from each frequencies that have a value of `WN`?