# Why splice method does not work and delete item on array in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, splice

I have an array type Person that has some data. Example:

```
const people = [{name: "John", age: "18"},{name: "Mike", content: "20"},{label: "Brand", content: "18"},{label: "Alice", content: "50"},{label: "Zina", content: "10"}];
```

I have another array type of string[] that has the following data:
`names=["John", "Zina"]`;

I try to delete the names that are on the second array from the first array like this:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
      if (names[j] === people[i].name) {
        people.splice(i);
      }
    }
  }
```

Why it does not work?

Comment: Why the sudden switch in the properties? Some have `name` while other have `label`..

Comment: `people.filter(({name}) => !names.includes(name))`

Comment: You are missing the second parameter to `splice`. It will delete all the items starting from `i`. Even if you change it to `people.splice(i, 1)`, it will break the loop because: [Looping through array and removing items, without breaking for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284). You need to loop in the reverse direction to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splice is modifying the original array. i.e. **on each iteration if condition return true, people array at that index gets replaced with undefined and hence gets error.**

you can use slice method to get data that you want to delete.

```
 for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
      if (names[j] === people[i].name) {
     console.log("matched",names[j],people[i].name, people.slice(i,i+1),);
      }
    }
  }
```

or you can simply filter data using Filter method.

Answer (score 2):

If you like to keep the object reference from `people`, you could iterate `people` from the end, because [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) with items to delete changes the indices of the following items.

```js
var people = [{ name: "Mike", content: "20" }, { label: "Brand", content: "18" }, { label: "Alice", content: "50" }, { label: "Zina", content: "10" }],
    names = ["John", "Zina"],
    i = people.length;

while (i--) {
    if (names.includes(people[i].name) || names.includes(people[i].label)) {
        people.splice(i, 1);
    }
}

console.log(people);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: property includes does not exist on type string []

Answer (score 1):

The `splice` method is modifying the array *inplace*.  I suggest you to use `filter` method.

```js
const people = [{name: "John", age: "18"},{name: "Mike", content: "20"},{name: "Brand", content: "18"},{name: "Alice", content: "50"},{name: "Zina", content: "10"}], names=["John", "Zina"];


console.log(people.filter(({name}) => !names.includes(name)));
```

Comment: This does not work while names is a type of string array

Comment: @KathrineHanson, then use indexOf instead includes

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below Code.

```js
const people = [{name: "John", age: "18"},{name: "Mike", content: "20"},{label: "Brand", content: "18"},{label: "Alice", content: "50"},{label: "Zina", content: "10"}];
const names = ["Mike","Shiv"];

for (let i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
debugger
    for (let j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
      if (names[j] === people[i].name) {
        people.splice(i,1);
      }
    }
  }
 console.log(people)
```