# p5.js - unable to read my update function at a random point in the program runtime

Tags: javascript, arrays, processing, p5.js

I am trying to create a program where particles generated on the left edge of the canvas get removed from the array (using splice) when they reach the right end of the canvas.

```
let P = [];
let n = 10;

function setup() 
{
    createCanvas(500,500);
    for(let i = 0; i < n; i++)
        P.push(new particle());
}

function draw() 
{
    background(0);
    for(let i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(P[i].out == true)
        {
            P.splice(i, 1);
            n--;
        }
        P[i].update();     
        P[i].plot();
        console.log(P.length)
    }   
}

class particle
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.brightness = 0;
        this.vel = random(1);
        this.dia = 3;
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = random(height);
        this.out = false;
    }

    update()
    {
        this.x += this.vel;
        if(this.x >= width)
            this.out = true;
    }

    plot()
    {
        noStroke();
        fill(255);
        circle(this.x, this.y, this.dia);
    }  
}
```

The program seems to be working fine for the most part when it runs. To make sure the elements in the array are actually being deleted, I tried logging the length of the array. 
When I run it, the elements get deleted as they reach the right end of the canvas but as the size of the array decreases to about 30% or so (its different every time I run it), I get this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined

I'm stumped by this because I don't understand how the update function is unable to be read when it has already been used several times in the loop previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is, that you remove elements from the array, while you iterate through the array. Note `P.splice(i, 1);`removes an element from the array if that was the last element in the array, then `P[i].update();` access the array out of bounds. That causes the error *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined"*

I recommend to travers the array from the back:
(See also [Looping through array and removing items, without breaking for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop))

```js
let i = P.length;
while (i--) {
    if (P[i].out == true) {
        P.splice(i, 1);
        n--;
    } else {
        P[i].update();     
        P[i].plot();
    }
}
```

See the example:

```js
let P = [];
let n = 10;

function setup() 
{
    createCanvas(500,500);
    for(let i = 0; i < n; i++)
        P.push(new particle());
}

function draw() 
{
    background(0);

    let i = P.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (P[i].out == true) {
            P.splice(i, 1);
        } else {
            P[i].update();     
            P[i].plot();
        }
    }   
}

class particle
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.brightness = 0;
        this.vel = random(1);
        this.dia = 3;
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = random(height);
        this.out = false;
    }

    update()
    {
        this.x += this.vel;
        if(this.x >= width)
            this.out = true;
    }

    plot()
    {
        noStroke();
        fill(255);
        circle(this.x, this.y, this.dia);
    }  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're removing elements from the array, you need to iterate through it backwards:

```
function draw() {
    background(0);
    for(let i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(P[i].out == true) {
            P.splice(i, 1);
            n--;
        }

        P[i].update();     
        P[i].plot();
        console.log(P.length)
    }   
}
```