# How to delete an entire javascript object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i have this array:

```
const hobbies = [{name:'Skate'}, {name:'Movies'}, {name:'Food'}]
```

Looping through i want to delete object where name is Skate

```
  for (const iterator of hobbies) {
    if(iterator === 'Skate'){
      delete object
    }
  }
```

Turns out, i think we cant delete a object literally, any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to delete it?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop

Comment: i want to delete the entire object @Christian

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript provides no mechanisms to explicitly delete objects.

You have to do it by deleting all references to the object instead. This will make it as eligible for garbage collection and it will be deleted when the garbage collector next does a sweep.

Since the only reference, in this example, to the object is as a member of an array you can remove it using `splice`.

```js
const hobbies = [{name:'Skate'}, {name:'Movies'}, {name:'Food'}]
const index_of_skate = hobbies.findIndex( object => object.name === 'Skate' );
hobbies.splice(index_of_skate, 1);
console.log(hobbies);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) would do the job:

```js
let hobbies = [{name:'Skate'}, {name:'Movies'}, {name:'Food'}]
hobbies = hobbies.filter((o) => o.name !== 'Skate');
console.log(hobbies);
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do that is to use the `filter` method on an array:

```
let hobbies = [{name:'Skate'}, {name:'Movies'}, {name:'Food'}]
hobbies = hobbies.filter(hobby => hobby.name !== 'Skate')
```

Just make sure to assign hobbies to the filtered array (like i did) since it doesn't modify the original array.

Comment: be careful, `hobbies` is `const`. You can't re-assign it