# removing duplicate in array (splice)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, duplicates, splice

I have a problem with splice duplicate items in array
here is what I have

```
users=[];

for(let i=0;i<30;i++) users.push({name: 'peter', number:'555'});

users.forEach((element, index, users) => {
  if((element.name === 'peter') && (element.number === '555')){
       users.splice(index, 1);
  }
});
```

for some reason, it deleting some of them but not all
same when I used for loop :/

any suggestions?

Comment: it is not a good idea to iterate with an array method and mutate the array at the same time.

Comment: if you simply need to remove duplicates, try set:
`users = [...new Set(users)];` should do the trick

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looping through array and removing items, without breaking for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop)

Comment: the problem is that `splice` immediately changes the length of your array, so `index` is now pointing at the "wrong" element

Comment: @corbin that's not going to work in this scenario. each object will have a different sharing reference

Answer (score 1):

You can remove in-place by iterating over the array backwards with a standard for-loop.

```js
const spliceWhere = (arr, predicate) => {
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (predicate(arr[i])) {
       arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  return arr; // Optional, for chaining
}

const users = new Array(30).fill({ name: 'peter', number: '555' });

console.log(JSON.stringify(users));

spliceWhere(
  users,
  ({ name, number }) => name === 'peter' && number === '555'
);

console.log(JSON.stringify(users));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The go-to solution for most would be to use the built-in method, `Array.prototype.filter`. This differs from Polywhirl's answer as it constructs a new array and replaces the old one -

```js
let users = [
  {name: 'peter', number:'555'},
  {name: 'alice', number:'555'},
  {name: 'peter', number:'111'},
  {name: 'bobby', number:'555'},
  {name: 'peter', number:'555'},
  {name: 'steve', number:'777'},
  {name: 'peter', number:'555'},
  {name: 'peter', number:'999'},
];

users = users.filter(({ name, number }) => {
  return !(name == "peter" && number == "555")
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(users));
```

```js
[ 
  {"name":"alice","number":"555"},
  {"name":"peter","number":"111"},
  {"name":"bobby","number":"555"},
  {"name":"steve","number":"777"},
  {"name":"peter","number":"999"}
]
```

Using [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) we can write an equivalent logical expression that may feel more natural for use with `filter` -

```js
let users = [
  {name: 'peter', number:'555'},
  {name: 'alice', number:'555'},
  {name: 'peter', number:'111'},
  {name: 'bobby', number:'555'},
  {name: 'peter', number:'555'},
  {name: 'steve', number:'777'},
  {name: 'peter', number:'555'},
  {name: 'peter', number:'999'},
];

users = users.filter(({ name, number }) => {
  return name != "peter" || number != "555"  // <- equivalent
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(users));
// []
```

```js
[ 
  {"name":"alice","number":"555"},
  {"name":"peter","number":"111"},
  {"name":"bobby","number":"555"},
  {"name":"steve","number":"777"},
  {"name":"peter","number":"999"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN documentation, [Modifying the array during iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#modifying_the_array_during_iteration)

> forEach() does not make a copy of the array before iterating.

E.g.

```js
let a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
a.forEach((n, I) => {
    console.log(n, I);
    a.shift();
});
```

Each time before `callback()` is invoked, the `I`-nd item of **CURRENT** `a` will be acquired. And `I` will be increased by 1 next time no matter `a` is changed or not, until it reaches at the end of **CURRENT** `a`.

So, you will get:

```sh
0 0
2 1
4 2
```