# How to remove multiple specific elements from an Array using a loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

Here is an Array of DOM elements, and I want to remove all those elements that have a certain class, in this case "checked-item". also I want to mutate the original array so I think filter method is out of the question.

```
taskArr = [some DOM Elements]
taskArr.forEach(function (task) {
 if (task.children[1].className.includes("checked-Item")) {
   taskArr.splice(taskArr.indexOf(task), 1);    
}
});
```

Comment: Why do you need to mutate the original array?

Comment: Your code looks like it should work. What doesn't work in it?

Comment: It removes some elements but not all. I don't know why @zhokya

Comment: @Usman-FE Can you provide a [mcve]? [It seems to work fine for me](https://jsfiddle.net/mp8wt41a/).

Comment: @Ivar add the class to consecutive elements and it won't work. `splice` will break the for loop.

Comment: Loop in the reverse direction or use a while loop as mentioned in the duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is probably because you splice elements inside loop, so if you console log the task, not every will be in output.
I found an solution, without foreach:

```
taskArr = [some DOM Elements]
const length = taskArr.length;
var deleted = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < length; i ++){
     if(taskArr[i - deleted].children[1].className.includes("checked-Item")){
         taskArr.splice(i - deleted, 1);
          deleted ++;
     }
}
```

Comment: Or you can loop from length to 0 in the reverse direction. You don't have to keep track of `deleted` in that case: [Looping through array and removing items, without breaking for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284)

Answer (score 0):

When a list is mutated while iterating, there can be side effects.  The splice can cause the subsequent item to be skipped. This is one reason immutable functions like `filter` are much easier to reason about.

Comment: Is there any way I can mutate the original Array using `filter` method?

Comment: @Usman-FE Assign the outcome back to the original array?

Comment: Generally after `filter` I would use `map` in order to modify the matched items.

Comment: I should add that if the subset of filtered items were not needed after processing, the `filter` could be followed with a `forEach`.