# Remove Specific Items from an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that is only supposed to contain 10 digit numbers. I am trying to eliminate entries in the array that contain a "-" symbol, but for some reason it is not working.

```
for(var z = 0; z<numArray.length; z++){
    if(numArray[z].includes("-")){
        numArray.splice(z, 0)
    }
}
```

is there something obvious that I am missing?

Comment: ```numArray.splice(z, 1)``` will work

Comment: The second argument to `splice` is the number of elements to remove at the index you've given in the first argument. `0` means "don't remove any," which is why nothing is being removed. Once you fix it, see the second issue in [the question marked by adiga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop).

Comment: @placementw - Not *quite*, in the code above. You also have to deal with the index issue.

Comment: Do not try to modify the length of an array you are iterating.

Comment: @TusharShahi OP is wanting to remove elements... so.. ya kinda do need to change the length to remove elements

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you're right, just pointed what was wrong in this piece of code since the proper logic way to handle the situation had already been marked = )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a classic that when removing elements from an array, you either need to iterate through the array backwards or decrement the `index` variable, otherwise you could skip over elements that are right next to each other that both should be deleted.

Also, having `0` for the second argument means "replace 0", or in this case, "remove 0", so changing that to `1` will remove the elements

```js
for(var z = 0; z<numArray.length; z++){
    if(numArray[z].includes("-")){
        numArray.splice(z, 1)
        z--;
    }
}
```

```js
for(var z = numArray.length-1; z >= 0; z--){
    if(numArray[z].includes("-")){
        numArray.splice(z, 1);
    }
}
```

However, it's easier to just use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). This function returns a new array with only elements that evaluate to true based on the passed in function, so we only want to keep the ones that DO NOT INCLUDE `"-"`

```js
numArray = numArray.filter((num) => !num.includes("-"));
```

Comment: Ah okay the re-indexing didn't even cross my mind. Makes total sense! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply filter:

```
let withoutDashes = numArray.filter(val => !val.includes('-'));
```