# Bringing numbers to the front

Tags: javascript

(Javascript)

```
functionName(“2 plus 3 is = 5!”);
```

would produce following message in console:

```
235 plus is =
```

I am unable to bring the numbers to the front, I am a little stumped

```js
function frontNum(str) {
  let emptyArr   = [];
  let rev        = str.split("");
  let expression = /[\d]/g;
   
  for(let i = 0; i < rev.length; i++) {
    if (rev[i].match(expression)) {
      emptyArr += rev.pop(rev[i]);
    }
  }
  console.log(emptyArr + rev.join(''));
}

frontNum("2 plus 3 is = 5!");
```

Answer (score 3):

Since this is your home work I won't give you the correct version, but give you some pointers instead:

1. your `emptyArr` is an array, but you are adding data to it as if it was a string.
2. take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop) topic, your `pop` causing problems
3. you can use your `expression` to capture all the digits and remove them from the string without need converting the string into array and loop through it (it can be done with 2 lines of code)

Comment: Nice constraint, max benefit to OP.

Answer (score 0):

a way todo that

```js
'use strict'

function frontNum(str)
  {
  let s = ''
    , n = ''  
  for (let x of str) 
    {
    if (/[0-9]/.test(x)) n += x 
    else                 s += x 
    }
  console.log( n + s.replace(/  +/g,' ') )
  }

frontNum('2 plus 3 is = 5!')
```