# Find all unique values in array and than split it and return something else

Tags: javascript, arrays

My goal is to find all the unique years in this array and than return it as a array. I have almost done it but cant figure out how I will return the split value.

```
function findUniqueYears() {
  const arr = ['1973-11-01', '2001-01-01', '1999-10-01', '2007-10-01', '2016-06-01', '2005-08-01', '1973-09-01', '1979-12-01', '2001-08-01'];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (arr[i].split("-")[0] === arr[j].split("-")[0]) {
        arr.splice(j, 1);
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(arr)
}
```

Comment: Look into using a `Set` for uniqueness. Then you should be able to convert that to an array.

Comment: The problem is that I only wanna find the unique years I don't really care for months and dates and Set will just find unique strings from what I can see

Comment: Don't splice an array while you're looping over it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop

Comment: `arr.join(" ").match(/\d{4}/g).filter((a,b,c)=>c.indexOf(a)==b);`

Comment: Put the result in a new array, and return that.

Comment: If your goal is to return the split value, a way to go around it, could be to declare an object and store the splitValue in it, then return the object, which would contain your splitValue when accessed

Comment: You aren't required to enter the entire array element into the `Set`; you can split out the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do

```
const findUniqueYears = (arr) => Array.from(new Set(arr.map(item => item.split('-')[0])))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function map to iterate via each element in the array then you can easily split date by '-' return 0 value and cast it to Set.

```js
function findUniqueYears() {
  const arr = ['1973-11-01', '2001-01-01', '1999-10-01', '2007-10-01', '2016-06-01', '2005-08-01', '1973-09-01', '1979-12-01', '2001-08-01'];
  return new Set(arr.map((el) => el.split('-')[0]))
}
```