# delete the localstorage item clicked on js

Tags: javascript, node.js

i wanna delete onclick the item in localstorage but the algo delete always the first element not the item clicked on in the html view

```
var array = [...deleteButton]

array.forEach((item, index) => 
{
    var id = item.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.dataset.id
    item.addEventListener("click", () => 
    {
        cart.forEach(elem =>
        {
            if(id === elem[0])
            {
                console.log(cart);
                cart.splice(elem, 1);
                location.reload();
                console.log(cart);
                localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart))
                console.log(index, elem[0]);
                console.log(cart);
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: The first argument to `cart.splice()` should be the index, not the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `splice()` has to be the index. Use `findIndex()` to get the index of the element with the matching value, and use that to splice.

```js
array.forEach((item, index) => {
  var id = item.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.dataset.id
  item.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let cartIndex = cart.findIndex(elem => id == elem[0]);
    if (cartIndex) {
      cart.splice(cartIndex, 1);
      localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
      location.reload();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: i already found the solution by myself by replacing the `elem` in `cart.splice` by `index` but thank you for yours it also worked fine !

Comment: You shouldn't splice an array while looping over it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop

Comment: i have another problem to solve if you can help me on it,

Comment: Post another question. If I see it and I'm interested in answering, I will.