# Variable read as undefined only in conditional statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local-storage, undefined

I have a jQuery function to remove items from a cart object that is stringified in local storage.

```
function removeItemFromCart(pid){
    console.log("removing: ", pid)
    let cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
    
    $.each(cart, function(index, value){
        console.log(value.productId);
        var p_id = value.productId;
        console.log(p_id);
        if (p_id == pid){
            cart.splice(index, 1);
            return;
        }
    });

    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));

}
```

However in my console I get the following error (for context my js file is cart.js):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'productId')
at cart.js:77:30
at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2:3003)
at removeItemFromCart (cart.js:76:11)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (cart.js:46:21)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2:43064)
at v.handle (jquery.min.js:2:41048)
(anonymous) @ cart.js:77
each @ jquery.min.js:2
removeItemFromCart @ cart.js:76
(anonymous) @ cart.js:46
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:2
v.handle @ jquery.min.js:2
```

and points to the p_id variable in the if-statement being undefined for some reason. Originally the if statement was `(value.productId == pid)` but I changed it to debug this very issue. I was testing things out and found that value.productId does exist in items in the cart in my local storage, that I am capable of saving it in a variable and even logging it without issue.

It is only when I try to use it in a conditional statement that it gets read as undefined but I have no clue as to why. Below is another function in the exact same file that essentially uses the exact same condition and it works fine without hiccups.

```
function updateCart(productId, quantity){
    let cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
    let foundProduct = false;
    $.each(cart, function(index, value){
        if (value.productId == productId){
            value.quantity += quantity;

            if (value.quantity < 0){
                cart.splice(index, 1);
            }
            foundProduct = true;
            return;
        }
    });
```

Does anybody know why this issue occurs and how I would go about debugging it?

For reproducability my local storage has a key called `cart` and a value of `[{"productId":2,"quantity":3},{"productId":6,"quantity":1},{"productId":5,"quantity":1}]`

Comment: Try if (this.p_id == pid)

Comment: You may want to review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*.

Comment: @Jeffery Ram I tried it and got no errors but the if statement was never fired. I did a console.log() on this.p_id and it returned undefined. Doing console.log() on p_id by itself gives the value I expect but throws an error when used in the if-statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had my analysis of the issue wrong.

Having `value.productId` in my conditional statements was not the issue by itself. After some debugging I found it was the fact that I was doing `cart.splice()` whilst iterating over the cart which messes things up with the index numbers the program uses during the loop. This is why it complained about the value being undefined.

The following stackoverflow post helped me identify my issue and presents various solutions to it, including iterating over the array in reverse: [looping through an array whilst removing items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop)