# Sort array without any sort methods using JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

My goal is not to use any Bubble/Section/Insertion/Merge/Quick Sort—nothing built in.

I am trying to figure out how to:

```js
let arr = [2, 8, 7, 3]

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  //here I want to number use numbers as an index let's say: arr[0] is 2 right? 
  // I want to set number 2 at index 2 - 1
  //arr[1] = at index 8 - 1 
  //arr[2] = at index 7 - 1
  //arr[3] = at index 3 - 1
  //output will be :    arr [2, 3, 7, 8]
  //here index of each num   ^  ^  ^  ^
  //                         1  2  6  7

 
}
```

here I tried to remove empty items but I lost whole numbers.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icxP2.png)

```js
let arr =[1,3,4,5,6]

let copyArr = [...arr]

copyArr[199] = 200
copyArr[149] = 150

console.log(copyArr)

let str = copyArr.toString().replaceAll(',','').split('')
console.log(str,)


// OUTPUT BELOW:


//copyArr:
// [ 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, <144 empty items>, 150, <49 empty items>, 200 ]

//str :
// [
//   '1', '3', '4', '5',
//   '6', '1', '5', '0',
//   '2', '0', '0'
// ]
```

Comment: Why are you creating all those undefined values in the first place?

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to have anything to do with sorting.

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense. Where are you doing the sorting? You're assigning indexes in the result after you have reordered them, but I don't understand why you're subtracting 1. Why can't you put `2` in index `2` instead of `1`. Also, what will you do if there are duplicate numbers in the array? They can't both go in the same index.

Comment: I'm trying to swap the index. as I said I don't want to use any built-in methods.
Idk which part confused you all of them are an example.
if we have numbers = [25, 17, 38, 98, 134, 5,] and I want to sort it WITHOUT ANY METHODS. if I set the last index of the array in this case number 5 which sits at index 6 and simply set it to 5 - 1 it will jump on at its original index which is index 4. if we do this to all these numbers whole array will be sorted.

Comment: What will you do if you have `numbers = [1, 2, 1]`?

Comment: I still don't understand why you need to subtract 1. Can't you do `result[25] = 25` instead of `result[24] = 25`? It will still be in the correct order.

Comment: let's figure first when there is Ascending order no repetitive numbers.

Comment: because the index starts at ---->0<------

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to subtract 1. Just assign each value to the corresponding index of the result array. This will work as long as all the values are non-negative integers and there are no duplicates. You don't have to ensure that the starting index is `0`, because the step that removes all the empty values will take care of that.

After this, you can use a simple `for` loop to splice out all the undefined elements that were created in the gaps.

```js
let result = [];
let arr = [2, 8, 7, 3];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  result[arr[i]] = arr[i];
}

// remove all the empty elements
for (let i = result.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (result[i] === undefined) {
    result.splice(i, 1);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

See [Looping through array and removing items, without breaking for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop) for why the second loop counts down instead of up.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about. you did a great job! what do you think about this approach? what will be big o for this?

Comment: `splice()` is O(n) because it has to shift all the following elements down, so it's O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

For your sorting question:

```js
let arr = [2, 8, 7, 3]

// from: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort-algorithms-by-using-javascript/
// Creating the bblSort function
function bblSort(arr) {

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    // Last i elements are already in place 
    for (var j = 0; j < (arr.length - i - 1); j++) {

      // Checking if the item at present iteration
      // is greater than the next iteration
      if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {

        // If the condition is true then swap them
        var temp = arr[j]
        arr[j] = arr[j + 1]
        arr[j + 1] = temp
      }
    }
  }
  
  return arr;
}

console.log(bblSort(arr).map(item => item - 1))
```

Comment: huh? This doesn't sort. It just subtracts 1 from every number.

Comment: @Barmar Exactly what OP asked for

Comment: oh wait, it does sort in his example

Comment: He's doing that to get the indexes *after* he has sorted them.