# In JavaScript, how to easily remove boolean values from an array consisting of numbers and booleans?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, validation, filter

In JavaScript, I have an array containing boolean values and integer numbers, eg

```
[1, true, 2, false, 3]
```

I want to get an array with the boolean values removed.  I tried

```
> [1, true, 2, false, 3].filter(Number)
[ 1, true, 2, 3 ]
```

Strangely, JavaScript thinks that `false` is not a Number, but true is.  How so?

If my array contains strings, it works.

```
> [1, '', 2, 'foo', 3].filter(Number)
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

I know I can write the following, I was hoping for an easier way.

```
> [1, true, 2, false, 3].filter(x => typeof x === 'number')
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

What's the easiest way to achieve what I want?

Thanks

Comment: `filter(item => typeof item !== 'boolean')`

Comment: *JavaScript thinks that false is not a Number, but true is.* It does not, try adding `0` to your array. `.filter(Number)` is interpreted approx. as `x => !!Number(x)` (of course you shouldn't write such thing in your code): parse to `Number` and check if it's not 0 or NaN.

Comment: `[0,'0',1,'1'].filter(Number)` returns `[ 1, '1' ]`. Thanks for pointing this out.  Guess I have to use the longhand

Comment: `filter(x => x!==!!x)`

Comment: The _"easiest"_ way is also the one that expresses exactly what is going to be achieved. Thus, the very expressive / readable / comprehensible last variant presented by the OP is the one to go with ... `[1, true, 2, false, 3].filter(x => typeof x === 'number')` ... and `typeof` is an operator and not a function. I fixed that in the originally posted code. Of cause one could be more expressive by writing an `isNumber` function which implements a number validation. Then the code becomes even more expressive ... `[1, true, 2, false, 3].filter(isNumber)`.

Comment: @ZackXu ... Regarding all the so far provided answers, are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0):

The `.filter()` method interprets the return value of the callback as boolean. If you use `Number()` as the filter callback, everything that evaluates to 0 or `NaN` will be excluded from the result.

What you really want to do is check the *type* of each value, which you can do with `typeof`.

Answer (score 0):

In case of just targeting [*integer*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger) or even [*safe integer*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger) values one could do ...

```
[1, true, 2, false, 3].filter(Number.isInteger);
```

... respectively ...

```
[1, true, 2, false, 3].filter(Number.isSafeInteger);
```

... that pretty much is the easiest to go with.

And from another of my above comments ...

> *The *"easiest"* way is also the one that expresses exactly what is going to be achieved. Thus, the very expressive / readable / comprehensible last variant presented by the OP is the one to go with ... `[1, true, 2, false, 3].filter(x => typeof x === 'number')` ...*
>
> *... Of cause one could be more expressive by writing an `isNumber` function which implements a number validation. Then the code becomes even more expressive ...*

```js
function isNumber(value) {
  return Object
    .prototype
    .toString
    .call(value) === '[object Number]';
}

function isNumberValue(value) {
  return typeof value === 'number';
}
function isFiniteNumberValue(value) {
  return isNumberValue(value) && Number.isFinite(value);
}
const testData = [1, true, 2, '', 3, 0/0, new Number(1111)];

console.log(
  'any number ...',
  testData.filter(isNumber)
);
console.log(
  'any number value ...',
  testData.filter(isNumberValue)
);
console.log(
  'any finite number value ...',
  testData.filter(isFiniteNumberValue)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
const list = [1, true, 2, false, 3];
const newList = list.filter(item => Number.isInteger(item));

console.log({ newList });
```

Comment: `isNumber` is not defined

Comment: Sorry for that, i fixed the code, hope this will work

Comment: Th parseInt function is used to convert string to integer and it gives NaN when it fails, you can use instead Number.isInteger to check if the item is number or not

Comment: Sorry i wrote parseInst instead of parseInt. My mistake

Comment: And yes i tested the code before i answer your question, but it is a typo error while writing the answer.

Comment: @GhadeerAhmad ... the [`radix` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#parameters) is still missing. And why didn't you use the edit to change it to [`Number.isInteger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger) as you already did mention yourself?

Comment: Here is the update. I edited it for you.

Answer (score -1):

`typeof`

```js
let array = [true, false, true, 1, true, 2, false, 3];

var i = array.length
while (i--) {
  if (typeof array[i] === 'boolean') { 
      array.splice(i, 1);
  } 
}

console.log(array)
```

Comment: This does not work (e.g. for `[true, false, 1, 2, 3]`) and is very inefficient anyway

Comment: Interesting. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop and all the related questions

Comment: Right. Fixed that.

Answer (score -2):

Using the input provided in your question, try this:
`[1, true, 2, false, 3].filter(el =>  (el === 0 || parseInt(el)));`
Or try this simpler one `[1, true, 2, false, 3].filter(Number.isInteger);`

Comment: @PeterSeliger it resolves the issue stated. In my answer I'm using the input provided by the OP. If more types of input need to be considered than the question can be updated.