# Find minimum, except zero

Tags: javascript

I'm using `Math.min()` to find the lowest price, but the variables passed might have `0` sometimes if the product is unavailable:

```
Math.min( 101.06, 99.99, 0 );
```

.. in this case, the result is `0`. How do I filter it out?

Comment: How is the variable passing zero? Can we see some more code, please?

Comment: You can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817756/delete-zero-values-from-array-with-javascript) to remove all values of 0 and just run `Math.min` on the filtered data

Comment: `Math.min.apply(null, [101.06, 99.99, 0].filter(Number))==99.99`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.apply` to pass arguments as an array,

> fun.apply(thisArg, [argsArray])

<sup>- [https://developer.mozilla.org/](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)</sup>

This means that you can filter your arguments, checking for any properties you would like.

So, in your case just do:

```js
Math.min.apply(this, [101.06, 99.99, 0].filter(Number) );
```

This method has other benefits as well, it seems like you would be dynamically generating your arguments, and it would be easier to pass a generated array than actual arguments.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you want the smallest positive number:

```
function positiveMin(arr) {
  var min;
  arr.forEach(function(x) {
    if (x <= 0) return;
    if (!min || (x < min)) min = x;
  });
  return min;
}

positiveMin([101.06, 99.99, 0, -1]); // => 99.99
positiveMin([0]); // => undefined
```

Comment: a solution based on reduce() would be faster than forEach()+closure in this case, but the code would be much the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple function:

```
Math.positiveMin = function(){
  arguments = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  return arguments.reduce(function(min, current){
    return (current > 0 && current < min) ? current : min;
  }, arguments[0]);
};
```

returns zero if there are no arguments greater than 0.

Possible benefit of this method over my previous: you were passing arguments individually in your example, and you can do that with this method:

```
Math.positiveMin( 101.06, 99.99, 0 );
```

will work just as you expect, no need for an array.